# How do I write a function in JS to return abbreviation of the words?

Tags: javascript, abbreviation

For example:

```
makeAbbr('central processing unit') === 'CPU'
```

I could not find my mistake. I appreciate your help.

```js
function makeAbbr(words) {
  let abbreviation = words[0];
  for (let i = 1; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (words[i] === '') {
      abbreviation += words[i + 1];
    }
  }
  return abbreviation.toUpperCase();
}

console.log(makeAbbr('central processing unit'));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to change the `words[i] === ''` into `words[i] === ' '`. `''` is an empty string.

Another option is splitting the passed string.

```
function makeAbbr(str) {
   // words is [ "central", "processing", "unit" ]
   let words = str.split(/\s+/);
   let abbreviation = '';
   for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
     abbreviation += words[i][0];
   }
   return abbreviation.toUpperCase();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This will generally work on abbreviation for words that use the first character of each words separated by a space.

```js
function makeAbbr(words) {
  // result abbreviation
  let abbreviation = '';
  // store each word into an array using split by space
  let wordArray = words.split(' ');
  // iterate through the word array
  for (let i = 0; i < wordArray.length; i++) {
    // take the first character in each word into the result abbreviation
    abbreviation += wordArray[i][0];
  }
  // return the abbreviation with all of them being upper case
  return abbreviation.toUpperCase();
}
// test case
console.log(makeAbbr('central processing unit'));
```

Answer (score 2):

A one liner solution:

```js
function makeAbbr(words) {
  return words.split(' ').map(word => word[0].toUpperCase()).join("");
}

console.log(makeAbbr('central processing unit'));
```

We are converting the `string` sentence to an array of *words separated by a space* (`.split(" ")`), then mapping or transforming every word in the array to its first letter, as well as capitalizing it: `.map(word => word[0].toUpperCase())`, then joining the array elements into a string with a "nothing" `""` as a separator:

`"central processing unit"` -> `["central", "processing", "unit"]` -> `["C", "P", "U"]` -> `"CPU"`

Answer (score 0):

```
const sample = ('central processing unit');

const makeAbrr = (word: string) => {
        return word.split(' ').map((letter) => letter[0].toUpperCase()).join('');
}

console.log(makeAbrr(sample));
```

Comment: `word: string` is a TypeScript thing, not JS.

Answer (score 0):

Regex version

```js
function makeAbbr(text) {
  if (typeof text != 'string' || !text) {
    return '';
  }
  const acronym = text
    .match(/[\p{Alpha}\p{Nd}]+/gu)
    .reduce((previous, next) => previous + ((+next === 0 || parseInt(next)) ? parseInt(next): next[0] || ''), '')
    .toUpperCase();
  return acronym;
}
console.log(makeAbbr('central processing unit'));
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65054252/2820150)