# How to capitalize first letter of each word, like a 2-word city?

Tags: javascript

My JS woks well when the city has one word:

- cHIcaGO ==> Chicago

But when it's

- san diego ==> San diego

How do I make it become San Diego?

```
function convert_case() {
    document.profile_form.city.value =
        document.profile_form.city.value.substr(0,1).toUpperCase() + 
        document.profile_form.city.value.substr(1).toLowerCase();
}
```

Answer (score 709, accepted):

There's a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196972/convert-string-to-proper-case-with-javascript/196991#196991):

```
function toTitleCase(str) {
    return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){
        return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
    });
}
```

or in ES6:

```
var text = "foo bar loo zoo moo";
text = text.toLowerCase()
    .split(' ')
    .map((s) => s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1))
    .join(' ');
```

Comment: thanks dexter this solution works perfectly for my needs

Comment: just wondering (might be a newbie question) but how does javascript know that the txt in `function(txt)` parameter is referring to `str`? Is it because you are calling `replace` on `str` so it can assume that?

Comment: it's not actually passing in `str` - it's passing in the "matched substring" - e.g. the result of the regex.  There's a good explanation on the Mozilla dev pages at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace, under the title `Specifying a function as a parameter`

Comment: Nice script but it doesn't work well for diacritics For example it will transform "anders ångström" into "Anders åNgström". If you need the script to handle such strings then check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15150168/title-case-in-javascript-for-diacritics-non-ascii

Comment: Might I recommend using `\b\w` instead of `\w\S*` as this will select the first letter of every word, even if the character inbetween is a slash or a dash rather than a space.

Comment: DOESN'T work for non-english words.

Comment: Shouldn't we not lowercase the substr(1) part of the string?  You may want to omit that, or make it optional.

Comment: `substr(1).toLowerCase()` converts everything except for the first character in each word to lower case - it's needed for the exact example that the OP posted (cHIcaGO ==> Chicago). You can omit the `toLowerCase()` if you don't want to force the rest of the string to be lower case, but you need to keep in `substr(1)` otherwise you'll end up with only the first character in each word!

Comment: would be nice if it didn't capitalize connecting words (and, for, this, that, etc.) as titles do not typically make these uppercase.

Comment: It wont work with accents... like "Úrsula"

Comment: Why using `\w`? It matches only ASCII chars (a-z, A-Z), but not for other languages. I used `/\.*\S*/g` as a regex and it seems to work fine for me.

Comment: This is my version based on @BearCode's link, compatible with diacritics, dashes, underscores, and single quotes. For example "gOOgle ångus OU_LIN ou'lin ou-lin" will be converted to "Google Ångus Ou_Lin Ou'Lin Ou-Lin":

`function toTitleCase(str)
{
 return str.toLowerCase().replace(/[^\s_'-]+/g, function (word)
 {
  return word.replace(/^./, function (firstLetter)
  {
   return firstLetter.toUpperCase();
  });
 });
}`

Comment: For ES6, it's an excellent use of reduce instead of map + join:

text = text.split(' ').reduce((acc, cv) => {
    return acc + " " + cv[0].toUpperCase() + cv.slice(1);
}, "").trim();

Comment: es6 best solution

Answer (score 151):

You can use CSS:

```
p.capitalize {text-transform:capitalize;}
```

#### Update (JS Solution):

Based on Kamal Reddy's comment:

```
document.getElementById("myP").style.textTransform = "capitalize";
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_text_text-transform.asp

Comment: thanks capdragon - but i need city names to be changed on client side AND saved in the database as capitalized -- i don't think CSS would allow for that, does it?

Comment: you can't just use the text-transform: capitalize for cHIcaGO ==> Chicago.  you would get CHIcaGO instead of Chicago. It simply transform only the first letter of the string.

Comment: css simply styles and renders, so you would still have to make sure the injected value is lowercased and first letter capped before inject into DB

Comment: please take a look at example i listed on my answer.

Comment: This does not work if the data is already uppercase

Comment: @capdragon, what I should have said was that 'capitalize' only changes the first letter to uppercase. So if your text is already in caps and you add 'capitalize' it just all stays in capital letters. Wish this wasn't the case but oh well :( http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-transform.asp

Comment: Downvoted because the question specifies JavaScript and you gave a solution using a different technology.

Comment: I agree with @RichardSmith-Unna, the question specifies how to do this with Javascript. This answering is the equivalent of answering "How do I divide numbers with pencil and paper" with, "Get a calculator and use the division function".

Comment: downvote due to not answering using the OPs requested language

Comment: downvote as the question is asked for Javascript, not CSS.

Comment: Downvoted because the original question asked for a JS solution, not CSS.

Comment: Upvoted because this answer offers a solution that works well for me.

Comment: for all the people who are hurt that the solution isnt in js. Here it is. 

document.getElementById("myP").style.textTransform = "capitalize";

Answer (score 26):

```
function convertCase(str) {
  var lower = String(str).toLowerCase();
  return lower.replace(/(^| )(\w)/g, function(x) {
    return x.toUpperCase();
  });
}
```

Comment: @enver's comment will not work since `String.toUpperCase` will be bound to the `String` object (`this` will be `String`, not the substring)

Comment: ES6 shortcut: `str.toLowerCase().replace(/(^| )(\w)/g, s => s.toUpperCase())`

Comment: @ClaudioHolanda: ... which is the same as in the answer :)

Comment: It don't work with accents, like "Úrsula"

Comment: @rakensi 's version doesnt work in IE 11 (and probably lower versions)

Comment: @rakensi I think you should erase your comment, I saw you already know it didn't work as expected so there is no point in leaving it there... (thanks for try anyway)

Answer (score 13):

The JavaScript function:

```
String.prototype.capitalize = function(){
       return this.replace( /(^|\s)([a-z])/g , function(m,p1,p2){ return p1+p2.toUpperCase(); } );
      };
```

To use this function:

```
capitalizedString = someString.toLowerCase().capitalize();
```

Also, this would work on multiple words string.

To make sure the converted City name is injected into the database, lowercased and first letter capitalized, then you would need to use JavaScript before you send it over to server side.  CSS simply styles, but the actual data would remain pre-styled.  Take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BgxMJ/1) example and compare the alert message vs the styled output.

Comment: Seems fine, but do not add this to `String.prototype`.

Comment: `if(!String.prototype.toTitleCase) {
  String.prototype.toTitleCase = function(){
    return this.toLowerCase().replace( /(^|\s)([a-z])/g , function(m,p1,p2){ return p1+p2.toUpperCase(); } );
  };
}` if you want to add to String.prototype and add a toLowerCase()

Comment: It don't work with accents, like "Úrsula"