# Regular expression for text field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to every word start with capital letter and rest of are should be in small letters while entering in text field.

I don't know how to give regular expression.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript - How to capitalize first letter of each word, like a 2-word city?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878756/javascript-how-to-capitalize-first-letter-of-each-word-like-a-2-word-city)

Comment: Means I wan "Adfsd Dfad Cadsf" like that

Comment: If you will enter capital letter it should not display.

Comment: Wait, do you want to do a replace or validation? If you want to validate (i.e., check user input) you want my answer; if you want to do a replace, accept the answer from @MaxArt.

Comment: while I entering it will be done

Comment: That doesn't clarify anything, unfortunately.  Do you want to *change the input* to conform to your format once it is entered, or do you want a *function that returns true or false* that tells whether your input matches your format?

Comment: Thank you for continuous effort "Apsillers". I got the output for my side. Please leave it.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use css [transform:capitalize](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-transform.asp), it would be easier? :D

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a classic capitalization function.

```
input.value = input.value.replace(/\b[a-zA-Z]+/g,
    function(m) {return m.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+m.substring(1).toLowerCase();})
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to validate some input, you should write a match for what you *don't* want and then negate it:

```
!( /\b[a-z]|\w[A-Z]/.test(input_string) )
```

This regex matches for lowercase letters at the start of a word or uppercase letters immediately after another letter (i.e., in the middle of a word). If you negate this result, as I have done here, you'll get the validation you want.

MDN has a good intro to [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) and the [JavaScript RegExp object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)