# Title Case in JavaScript for diacritics (non-ASCII)

Tags: javascript, case, title

Is it possible to create a JavaScript function that can convert a string to title case but one that works with non-ASCII (Unicode) characters? For example with characters like:

```
Áá  Àà  Ăă  Ắắ  Ằằ  Ẵẵ  Ẳẳ  Ââ  Ấấ  Ầầ  Ẫẫ  Ẩẩ  Ǎǎ  Åå  Ǻǻ  Ää  Ǟǟ  Ãã
Éé  Èè  Ĕĕ  Êê  Ếế  Ềề  Ễễ  Ểể  Ěě  Ëë  Ẽẽ  Ėė  Ȩȩ  Ḝḝ  Ęę  Ēē  Ḗḗ  Ḕḕ
etc.
```

For example if the string is "anders ångström", it should transform it into "Anders Ångström".
The script that [already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196972/convert-string-to-title-case-with-javascript) it will transform into "Anders åNgström".

Comment: `'å'.toUpperCase()` works for me...

Comment: yes toUpperCase() works for me too but the Title Case function doesn't work for words beginning with 'å' because JavaScript won't inclulde it correctly into "entire words" (\w)

Comment: Oh I see, check my answer, it can still be done without `\w`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this:

```
var str = 'anders ångström';

str = str.replace(/[^\s]+/g, function(word) {
  return word.replace(/^./, function(first) {
    return first.toUpperCase();
  });
});

console.log(str); //=> "Anders Ångström"
```

Comment: Sorry I just noticed it doesn't work for names containing dash ("-"), like for example "luise meyer-schützmeister". It will transform it into "Luise Meyer-schützmeister". Any chance you can improve it?

Comment: To support dashes and single quotes, change /[^\s]+/g  to /[^-'\s]+/g

Answer (score -1):

Javascript's built-in conversion is Unicode-aware, for instance `"å".toUpperCase()` returns `"Å"`.  So I'm not sure what your "existing script" is doing wrong.

If, however, you need full Unicode-aware case conversion (or other Unicode suport), you may want to look at [unicode.js](https://github.com/reyesr/javascript-unicode).

Comment: Thanks. Anyways I need a Title Case function (a better version of toTitleCase() from the link above) that works with non-ASCII too. The Title Case function is a combination of uppercase and entire word matching functions.