# Lowercase all letters in a string except the first letter and capitalize first letter of a string? - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string

I.e., if I have an input string:

```
input = 'hello World, whatS up?'
```

I want an output string to be:

desiredOutput = 'Hello World, whats up?'

If the first letter of any word in the string is already in upper case, leave it as is.

Comment: Do you really want "whats up" or rather "Whats Up"?

Comment: Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/how-do-i-make-the-first-letter-of-a-string-uppercase-in-javascript

Comment: input.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + input.toLowerCase().substring(1, txt.length);

Comment: @SMA that lowercases all letters except the first letter of the first word. I essentially do not want to not lowercase the first letter if it is uppercase already

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make the first letter of a string uppercase in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/how-do-i-make-the-first-letter-of-a-string-uppercase-in-javascript)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```js
const upperCaseFirstLetter = string =>
 `${string.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase()}${string.slice(1)}`;

const lowerCaseAllWordsExceptFirstLetters = string =>
 string.replaceAll(/\S*/g, word =>
  `${word.slice(0, 1)}${word.slice(1).toLowerCase()}`
 );

const input = 'hello World, whatS up?';
const desiredOutput = upperCaseFirstLetter(lowerCaseAllWordsExceptFirstLetters(input));

console.log(desiredOutput);
```

Based on:

[How do I make the first letter of a string uppercase in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/how-do-i-make-the-first-letter-of-a-string-uppercase-in-javascript)

and

[How to capitalize first letter of each word, like a 2-word city?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878756/javascript-how-to-capitalize-first-letter-of-each-word-like-a-2-word-city)

Comment: I like what u did here but how about replacing the regex for function lowerCaseAllWordsExceptFirstLetters with this : /([^\s]+)/g
so that it works for all words, I had issues with some words such as "İSTANBUL" , so I came up with this comment

Answer (score 33):

```
word = word.charAt(0) + word.substring(1).toLowerCase();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While your code may provide the answer to the question, please add context around it so others will have some idea what it does and why it is there.

Comment: @Theo Normally I would agree with what you wrote but this answer is pretty self-explanatory.

Answer (score 10):

I was trying to do the same and I found a shorter way to do it:

```js
function formatString(str) {
  return str
    .replace(/(\B)[^ ]*/g, match => (match.toLowerCase()))
    .replace(/^[^ ]/g, match => (match.toUpperCase()));
}

var text = "aaa BBB CCC";
console.log(formatString(text));
```

Comment: Shorter isn't necessarily better; your answer is far less readable than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
function titleCase(str) {
  return str.split(' ').map(item => 
         item.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + item.slice(1).toLowerCase()).join(' ');
}

console.log(titleCase("HERE IS MY HANDLE HERE IS MY SPOUT"));

// It prints "Here Is My Handle Here Is My Spout";
```

Change the `str` parameter values and you are good to go.