# How to convert non-UTC dates into UTC date format in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, datetime, subtraction

How to subtract from
`year:2026 month:JAN day:26` - `year:2025 month:NOV day:27` in JavaScript

My firstDate: `year:2026 month:JAN day:26`
My second date: `year:2025 month:NOV day:27`

So how can I find the difference between these two dates in JavaScript?

I was expecting to subtract them by using `getTime()` but it’s returning Invalid Date

Or another word is there another way to subtract dates in non UTC format?

If not how can I convert those dates to UTC format?

Note: I’m receiving those dates from API  response and both dates are String

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO: [Date difference](https://www.google.com/search?q=subtract+OR+difference+dates+javascript+site%3Astackoverflow.com) and [dd mmm yyyy dates](https://www.google.com/search?q=convert+dd+mmm+yyyy+to+date+javascript+site:stackoverflow.com) if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: @MisterJojo where is the timezone? If there is no time, calculate in absolute days: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/mqy2b4gx/

Comment: this calculation is distorted if the 2 dates are different summer/winter daytimes.

Comment: no timezone on both dates

Comment: The only thing I need is to find the difference between those dates to ensure that difference is 30 days but how can I calculate in absolute days? 
Thanks!

Comment: Actually I don't have to create a UTC date. The only reason I wanted to convert to UTC is to make calculation between the dates. If I can make a calculation without converting to UTC, that's fine. 
Sorry I'm very new to JavaScript!

Comment: It is possible to make a difference between 2 dates, with `YMD` information you will only be able to obtain at best a difference in number of days. a UTC date difference does this in milliseconds. Try to be more specific in your next questions

Comment: Is there a specific method that I can use to find difference in days? 
I tried to use getTime() but getting invalid date error. 
Also tried this -> const diff = Math.abs(d1-d2); but it didn't work.
 Thanks!

Comment: no, just use the result of `date_A - date_B` , (result is millisecond, to divide by day duration in ms)

Comment: let date1 = new Date("2026-01-26").getDate();

let date2 = new Date("2025-11-27").getDate(); 

let result = date1-date2;
but it's returning 0

Thanks!

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40195766/lowercase-all-letters-in-a-string-except-the-first-letter-and-capitalize-first-l

Comment: `let delta = (new Date('Jan 26, 2026') - new Date('Nov 27, 2025')) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);`

Comment: Thanks so much for help! 
I'm able to solve my calculation issue now

Comment: @MisterJojo—that is not a good way to get difference in days. Not all days are 24 hours long in places that observe daylight saving. Also, parsing of unsupported date formats is implementation dependent so might produce unexpected results. These issues are covered in the duplicates so the OP should be directed there.

Comment: I'm wondering if in the case of calculation problems  with daylight saving, simply use `math.round((d1 - d2) / 86400000)` will do the job?