# Unexpected result with Regular Expression in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

This is my String.

```
 var re = "i have a string";
```

And this my expression

```
var str = re.replace(/(^[a-z])/g, function(x){return x.toUpperCase();});
```

I want that it will make the the first character of any word to Uppercase. But the replacement above return only the first character uppercased. But I have added /g at the last.

---

Where is my problem?

Comment: So whats your desired output?

Comment: The `^` character means the start of the line, not the start of the word. That's the problem.

Comment: there is an answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878756/how-to-capitalize-first-letter-of-each-word-like-a-2-word-city

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to capitalize first letter of each word, like a 2-word city?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878756/how-to-capitalize-first-letter-of-each-word-like-a-2-word-city)

Comment: https://regexper.com/ paste your req exp in there and you will see why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `\b` to mark a boundary to the expression.

```js
const re = 'i am a string';

console.log(re.replace(/(\b[a-z])/g, (x) => x.toUpperCase()));
```

> The metacharacter \b is an anchor like the caret and the dollar sign. It matches at a position that is called a "word boundary". This match is zero-length.
>
> There are three different positions that qualify as word boundaries:
>
> 1. Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a word character.
> 2. After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.
> 3. Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

Comment: Thanks Felixmosh.
But could you please explain what the \b effects or it's work.

Comment: So, do that catch expression in Every Word not line?

Comment: Exactly, it is a "word boundary". Check out the example.

Answer (score 0):

Vlaz' comment looks like the right answer to me -- by putting a "^" at the beginning of your pattern, you've guaranteed that you'll only find the first character -- the others won't match the pattern despite the "/g" because they don't immediately follow the start of the line.

Comment: So you have a recommendation how the OP should actually solve their problem?

Comment: Yeah, I should have added that -- the linked article was good, but it's better if the answer encapsulates it. Now there's already good answer, so I'll leave it.