# I'm trying to make every word that comes up as an acronym plus it always has to be a capital letter using loops

Tags: javascript, charat, acronym

Hi so basically I have a prompt that will make the user enter a phrase or phrases and when I return it I need to make each word an acronym and capital letter, for example:  If I wrote "hello welcome to canada" it should come up as "HWTC".  I have to use a either a for loop or while loop to do this and this is what I have right now but not sure how to make it so every word comes up as an acronym instead of just the first word I write.  Thanks

```
function acronym () {
   let word = prompt("enter a word that you want to change into an acronym")
   let result = word
   while (word.charAt(4) === "") {
       word = word.charAt(0)
       word = word.toUpperCase()
   } document.getElementById("string").innerHTML = result;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to capitalize first letter of each word, like a 2-word city?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878756/how-to-capitalize-first-letter-of-each-word-like-a-2-word-city)

Comment: That isn't right, I need to use a for or while loop to do this.  While the link you gave me gave me some solution, it isn't the one I'm looking for