# How to convert into proper case while typing in Javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do you convert text that you type into proper case as you type?

**Example:** “The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog”

**Edit-01:** I want to make sure that it works On-Type. I found different methods to make this work On-Blur, but not On-Type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to capitalize first letter of each word, like a 2-word city?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878756/how-to-capitalize-first-letter-of-each-word-like-a-2-word-city)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string to title case with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196972/convert-string-to-title-case-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```js
function toTitleCase(s) {
  return s.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(t) {
    return t.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + t.substr(1).toLowerCase();
  });
}
```

```html
<input onkeyup="this.value=toTitleCase(this.value)" />
```

Comment: It works! Thank you :)