# Capitalize the first letter of every word

Tags: javascript

I want to use a javascript function to capitalize the first letter of every word

eg:

```
THIS IS A TEST ---> This Is A Test
this is a TEST ---> This Is A Test
this is a test ---> This Is A Test
```

What would be a simple javascript function

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/capitalize-the-first-letter-of-string-in-javascript

Comment: Turn to lower case, cut into individual words by splitting by whitespace, toUpperCase() on the first char of each word.

Comment: @reader_1000: that question is about uppercasing just the first char of a string while this is about uoppercasing the first char of every word (wich is way more complicated and needs a different solution)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert string to title case with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196972/convert-string-to-title-case-with-javascript)

Comment: kinda the point of CSS right... to "style" the dom? text-transform: capitalize;

Answer (score 36):

Here's a little one liner that I'm using to get the job done

```
var str = 'this is an example';
str.replace(/\b./g, function(m){ return m.toUpperCase(); });
```

but John Resig did a pretty awesome script that handles a lot of cases 
http://ejohn.org/blog/title-capitalization-in-javascript/

**Update**

ES6+ answer:

`str.split(' ').map(s => s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.slice(1)).join(' ');`

There's probably an even better way than this. It will work on accented characters.

Comment: I love how simple and succinct this one is.

Comment: try the updated answer. sadly `\b` won't pick special chars

Answer (score 10):

```
function capitalizeEachWord(str)
{
   var words = str.split(" ");
   var arr = [];
   for (i in words)
   {
      temp = words[i].toLowerCase();
      temp = temp.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + temp.substring(1);
      arr.push(temp);
   }
   return arr.join(" ");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
"tHiS iS a tESt".replace(/[^\s]+/g, function(str){ 
    return str.substr(0,1).toUpperCase()+str.substr(1).toLowerCase();
  });
```

Other variant:

```
"tHiS iS a tESt".replace(/(\S)(\S*)/g, function($0,$1,$2){ 
    return $1.toUpperCase()+$2.toLowerCase();
  });
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a simple solution that breaks down the sentence into an array, then loops through the array creating a new array with the capitalized words.

```
 function capitalize(str){

  var strArr = str.split(" ");
  var newArr = [];

  for(var i = 0 ; i < strArr.length ; i++ ){

    var FirstLetter = strArr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase();
    var restOfWord = strArr[i].slice(1);

    newArr[i] = FirstLetter + restOfWord;

  }

  return newArr.join(' ');

}
```

Answer (score 1):

take a look at [ucwords from php.js](http://phpjs.org/functions/ucwords:569) - this seems to be kind of what you're looking for. basically, it's:

```
function ucwords (str) {
    return (str + '').replace(/^([a-z])|\s+([a-z])/g, function ($1) {
        return $1.toUpperCase();
    });
}
```

note that `THIS IS A TEST` will return `THIS IS A TEST` so you'll have to use it like this:

```
var oldstring = "THIS IS A TEST";
var newstring = ucwords(oldstring.toLowerCase());
```

or modify the function a bit:

```
function ucwords (str) {
    str = (str + '').toLowerCase();
    return str.replace(/^([a-z])|\s+([a-z])/g, function ($1) {
        return $1.toUpperCase();
    });
}
var oldstring = "THIS IS A TEST";
var newstring = ucwords(oldstring); // This Is A Test
```

Answer (score 1):

This will capitalize every word seperated by a space or a dash

```
function capitalize(str){
    str = str.toLowerCase();
    return str.replace(/([^ -])([^ -]*)/gi,function(v,v1,v2){ return v1.toUpperCase()+v2; });
}
```

Examples :

- i lOvE oRanges => I Love Oranges
- a strAnge-looKing syntax => A Strange-Looking Syntax

etc

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using a library, you could use [**Sugar.js**](http://sugarjs.com/) [**capitalize()**](http://sugarjs.com/api/String/capitalize)

> **capitalize( all = false )** Capitalizes the first character in the
>   string and downcases all other letters. If all is true, all words in
>   the string will be capitalized.

Example:

```
'hello kitty'.capitalize()     -> 'Hello kitty'
'hello kitty'.capitalize(true) -> 'Hello Kitty'
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use below approach using filter:

```
function Ucwords(str){
    var words = str.split(' ');
    var arr = [];
    words.filter(function(val){
        arr.push(val.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+ val.substr(1).toLowerCase());             
    })
    console.log(arr.join(" ").trim());
    return arr.join(" ").trim();
}

Ucwords("THIS IS A TEST") //This Is A Test

Ucwords("THIS ") //This
```

Answer (score -1):

```
{
        String s = "this is for testing";
        String sw[] = s.split("\\s");
        String newS = "";
        for(int i=0; i<=sw.length-1; i++)
        {
            String first = sw[i].substring(0,1);
            String last = sw[i].substring(1);
            newS+= first.toUpperCase()+last+" ";
            
        }
        System.out.println(newS);
    }
```