# Remove stop words

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to remove stopwords from a string with a single `.replace()` because I figured out it brings the best performance in [this performance test](http://jsperf.com/stop-words-removal). But I have problems when two stop words follow each other, like in the snippet below:

```
var stopWordsRE = /((?:^|\s+?)(foo|bar)(?:$|\s+?))/gi;
var text = "foo bar baz bar foobar";
var filtered = text.replace(stopWordsRE, " ");
console.log(filtered); // bar baz foobar
```

But it's supposed to return:

```
baz foobar
```

The problem is that the regular expression matches `foo` and the succeeding whitespace, such that there is no preceding whitespace anymore for `bar` to match. I thought the non-capturing groups would suffice, such that the whitespace is not remembered. But apparently not, can you tell me how to fix the regex such that it matches stopwords following each other?

Comment: This seems like a homework problem.

Comment: I can assure you, it is not. But if the solution is simple or somehow obvious, I apologise...

Comment: @rob It doesn't seem like a homework problem. And even if it did, you did a lot more than most people that come here with a homework problem asking for a solution

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: The expected output is in the question: `baz  foobar`

Comment: @rob use lookahead. See http://regex101.com/r/xH3iL5/5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of matching the space after `foo or bar` you need to use **positive lookahead**:

```
var stopWordsRE = /(?:^|\s+)(?:foo|bar)(?=\s+|$)/gi;
var filtered = text.replace(stopWordsRE, "").trim();
//=> "baz foobar"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to match using word boundaries: `\b`

```
var stopWordsRE = /(\b(foo|bar)\b\s*)/gi;
```

That matches multiple times on the line (`g` flag), case-insensitive (`i` flag), as you already had.

And it matches any `foo` or `bar` that is a full word. That is both ends of the string are bounded by [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), which are zero-length anchors that correspond the beginning or ending of words.

Finally, the `\s*` grabs any (or no) whitespace along side the word, so you don't end up with multiple spaces in between the remaining words.

Comment: This does indeed solve the problem from the question and is also an improvment. But it seems to have troubles with german umlaute. It matches the `bar` in `häbar`. At least in Chrome, but this might also be a bug in V8. Will test it in other browsers as well.

Comment: @rob Good point. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10590098/javascript-regexp-word-boundaries-unicode-characters

Comment: I like this solution better but with the current mess with JS and unicode it's not an option.