# How to select a word only with single character using regex?

Tags: regex

I have more words -like apple, orange, banana, a , b , c.
i want to select a word with single character only using regex?
what to do?

i mean only a, b, c.(answer)

Could anyone help me?

Comment: where is your current regex?

Comment: @Ani You mean this `\b[A-Za-z]\b` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should match a single letter between word boundaries

```
/\b(\w)\b/
```

Comment: With the caveat that it won't work on non-ASCII characters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10590098/javascript-regexp-word-boundaries-unicode-characters

Answer (score 1):

The following matches single-character words. `\b` matches a word boundary, and `\w` a word character.

```
\b\w\b
```