# regex to match all words but AND, OR and NOT

Tags: javascript, regex

In my javascript app I have this random string:

`büert AND NOT 3454jhadf üasdfsdf OR technüology AND (bar OR bas)`

and i would like to match all words special chars and numbers besides the words `AND`, `OR` and `NOT`.

I tried is this

`/(?!AND|OR|NOT)\b[\u00C0-\u017F\w\d]+/gi`
which results in
`["büert", "3454jhadf", "asdfsdf", "technüology", "bar", "bas"]`

but this one does not match the `ü` or any other letter outside the a-z alphabet at the beginning or at the end of a word because of the `\b` word boundary.

removing the `\b` oddly ends up matching part or the words i would like to exclude:

`/(?!AND|OR|NOT)[\u00C0-\u017F\w\d]+/gi`
result is
`["büert", "ND", "OT", "3454jhadf", "üasdfsdf", "R", "technüology", "ND", "bar", "R", "bas"]`

what is the correct way to match all words no matter what type of characters they contain besides the ones i want exclude?

Comment: Closely related: [Javascript RegExp + Word boundaries + unicode characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10590098/javascript-regexp-word-boundaries-unicode-characters)

Comment: The `(?:^|\\s)` solution in the linked question above will exclude all matches after/before punctuation and in similar contexts. Negated character class should be used to ensure the same functionality as with `\b`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here has its roots in the fact that `\b` (and `\w`, and other shorthand classes) are not Unicode-aware in JavaScript.

Now, there are 2 ways to achieve what you want.

## 1. SPLIT WITH PATTERN(S) YOU WANT TO DISCARD

```js
var re = /\s*\b(?:AND|OR|NOT)\b\s*|[()]/;
var s = "büert AND NOT 3454jhadf üasdfsdf OR technüology AND (bar OR bas)";
var res = s.split(re).filter(Boolean);
document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(res, 0, 4);
// = > [ "büert", "3454jhadf üasdfsdf", "technüology", "bar", "bas" ]
```

Note the use of a non-capturing group `(?:...)` so as not to include the unwanted words into the resulting array. Also, you need to add all punctuation and other unwanted characters to the character class.

## 2. MATCH USING CUSTOM BOUNDARIES

You can use groupings with anchors/reverse negated character class in a regex like this:

```
(^|[^\u00C0-\u017F\w])(?!(?:AND|OR|NOT)(?=[^\u00C0-\u017F\w]|$))([\u00C0-\u017F\w]+)(?=[^\u00C0-\u017F\w]|$)
```

The capure group 2 will hold the values you need.

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vX0rY5/2)

JS code demo:

```js
var re = /(^|[^\u00C0-\u017F\w])(?!(?:AND|OR|NOT)(?=[^\u00C0-\u017F\w]|$))([\u00C0-\u017F\w]+)(?=[^\u00C0-\u017F\w]|$)/gi; 
var str = 'büert AND NOT 3454jhadf üasdfsdf OR technüology AND (bar OR bas)';
var m;
var arr = []; 
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
  arr.push(m[2]);
}
document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(arr);
```

or with a block to build the regex dynamically:

```js
var bndry = "[^\\u00C0-\\u017F\\w]";
var re = RegExp("(^|" + bndry + ")" +                   // starting boundary
           "(?!(?:AND|OR|NOT)(?=" + bndry + "|$))" +    // restriction
           "([\\u00C0-\\u017F\\w]+)" +                  // match and capture our string
           "(?=" + bndry + "|$)"                        // set trailing boundary
           , "g"); 
var str = 'büert AND NOT 3454jhadf üasdfsdf OR technüology AND (bar OR bas)';
var m, arr = []; 
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
  arr.push(m[2]);
}
document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(arr);
```

**Explanation:**

- `(^|[^\u00C0-\u017F\w])` - our custom boundary (match a string start with `^` or any character outside the `[\u00C0-\u017F\w]` range)
- `(?!(?:AND|OR|NOT)(?=[^\u00C0-\u017F\w]|$))` - a restriction on the match: the match is failed if there are `AND` or `OR` or `NOT` followed by string end or characters other than those in the `\u00C0-\u017F` range or non-word character
- `([\u00C0-\u017F\w]+)` - match word characters (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) or those from the `\u00C0-\u017F` range
- `(?=[^\u00C0-\u017F\w]|$)` - the trailing boundary, either string end (`$`) or characters other than those in the `\u00C0-\u017F` range or non-word character.

Comment: This does not look readable due to the restriction to skip AND/OR/NOT. Perhaps, you could use blocks to build the RegExp dynamically to make it more readable.

Comment: I think this is too complicated regex and you should add the `split` solution.

Comment: Or close as a dupe then. Still there is a difference between these 2 solutions. Although this regex might look monstrous, it is actually a valid way of defining custom boundaries in JS.