# How to replace words with special symbol (.) in string?

Tags: php, string, preg-replace

I have sample string:

```
$string = "муқ. - муқоиса муқ. муқ.шавад муқ томуқ.";
```

I try with this my code:

```
$result = preg_replace("/\b(муқ\.?)\b/u", 'repl', $string);
echo "$result";
```

**Result:**
repl. - муқоиса repl. replшавад repl томуқ.

**Needed result:** ***repl*** - муқоиса ***repl*** муқ.шавад муқ томуқ.

Here I can't replace word with "." ended symbol!

Comment: `\b` doesn't work good with unicode characters.. You can try [a proposed workaround here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45985701/7393478)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$result = preg_replace("/\bмуқ\.\B/u", "repl", $string);
```

The shared link: https://regex101.com/r/zPXOtP/1

Answer (score 1):

Use a negative lookahead:

```
$result = preg_replace("/\bмуқ\.(?!\w)/u", 'repl', $string);
```

Comment: How I can use instead `муқ` array words in pattern? I have many words ended with '.'

Comment: preg_replace("/\b(one|two|three)\.(?!\w)/u", "replace", $string)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the **str_replace** function.

```
str_replace(".", "your word", "your string");
```