# JavaScript capitalize first letter of string that contains Turkish character

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, capitalize, turkish

I aim to capitalize just first letter of each word in a string. (The other letters of the strings must be lowercase)

I have checked similar questions but could not find an exact solution for unicode characters.

For example

My string **"şöhret için önce çalışmak/gerek"**

I want to have **"Şöhret İçin Önce Çalışmak/Gerek"**

My solution does not work for Turkish characters:

```
myStr.toLocaleLowerCase("TR").replace(/\b[a-zığüşöç](?=[a-zığüşöç]{0})/g, function(letter) {
    return letter.toLocaleUpperCase("TR"); } );
```

Result for solution above:

**"şöHret İÇİn öNce çAlIşMak/Gerek"**

I also used hexadecimal representation of Turkish character but result did not changed

Comment: Remove `\b`, use a Unicode equivalent. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EV8jn9/1).

Comment: Thanks but does not work in jsvascript

Comment: It works in JavaScript, the regex flavor is JS in the demo. If you want to use custom boundaries, use solutions from [Javascript RegExp + Word boundaries + unicode characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10590098/javascript-regexp-word-boundaries-unicode-characters). E.g. those based on XRegExp.

Comment: Wiktor. Could you please write a complete JavaScript function? I could not achieve it.

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/wiktor_stribizew/pv06juhw/1/