# Need to search arabic text in my web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, full-text-search

I have the following code which works fine for english but not working for arabic. how can i use this code for arabic also. how can I serach it as a string

```
    function highlightSearch() {
    var text = document.getElementById("query").value;
    var query = new RegExp("(\\b" + text + "\\b)", "gim");
    var e = document.getElementById("nav-5-3-primary-ver").innerHTML;
    var enew = e.replace(/(<h6>|<\/h6>)/igm, "");
    document.getElementById("nav-5-3-primary-ver").innerHTML = enew;
    var newe = enew.replace(query, "<h6>$1</h6>");
    document.getElementById("nav-5-3-primary-ver").innerHTML = newe;
    }
```

```
    #nav-5-3-primary-ver h6{
    background-color:#FF9;
    color:#555;
}
```

```
     <input name="query" id="query" type="text" size="30" maxlength="30">
     <input name="searchit" type="button" value="Search" onClick="highlightSearch()">

      <div id="nav-5-3-primary-ver"> 
       hello i am this
      </br>
      اذا كان الجهاز خارج التغطية هل يتم تسجيل البيانات للسيارة؟
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a gotcha with `\b` (in javascript at least) : the notion of "word" it uses (to detect word boundaries) is :

- sequences of characters in the set `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` (latin alphanumerics, plus the `_` char)

It won't work as you expect for other charsets (note : even [latin diacritics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10590098/javascript-regexp-word-boundaries-unicode-characters) - letters with accents or signs on them - don't work).

---

Choose some other way to chek that you matched a complete word :

- as suggested [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10590098/javascript-regexp-word-boundaries-unicode-characters) : you can write a predicate that matches "a space character or `^` or `$`"
- or match the word without boundaries, and for each match, inspect the characters prior and next to that match

---

Links to ECMAscript specifications :

- [Assertions in Regular Expressions](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-assertion)
- [Word Character definition](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-wordcharacters-abstract-operation)

Comment: That's sad, I think a solution based on `\p{Letter}` can also be devised