# How to remove dashes and change the first words to caps?

Tags: jquery

I want to convert this key some_name and change it to Some Name.

How can i replace the dash and change the first letter of the words to caps for the key only

```
var data = $(this).serializeObject();
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
var tablefeed = $('<tr><td>'+key+'</td><td id="'+key+'">'+val+'</td><tr>').appendTo('#display');
                    });
    $(".modal-body").html(tablefeed);
```

current output
key            | val

```
some_name_11_ar_22     | joe
```

Expected output

```
Some Name  11 ar 22   | joe
```

Comment: for the replace use **.replace("_"," ");**

Comment: Have you attempted anything yet? It could be done with a regular expression, or indexOf etc. RegExp would be easiest.

Comment: You can capitalize first letters with a regular expression.  See [this related SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196972/convert-string-to-title-case-with-javascript/196991#196991).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace a dash you can simple do this:

```
key = key.replace(/_/g, ' ');
```

And to capitalize words I would suggest you to use CSS instead of javascript, since it seems that it's only needed for representation purposes:

```
... '<td class="keys">' + key + '</td>' ...
```

CSS:

```
td.keys {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```