# Javascript/jQuery uppercase first letter of variable with accents

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, uppercase

I have a form with some text inputs to insert `First Name`, `Last Name` of a person, but I want to change the first letter of each word to a Uppercase and I found this solution:

```
 // The textboxes with this class are modified
 $(".toUpper").change(function () {
        var str = $(this).val();
        str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function (letter) {
            return letter.toUpperCase();

        });
        $(this).val(str);
    });
```

and it works, `("hEllO"=>"Hello", "whAts uP" =>"Whats Up")`.

The problem occurs when I try to apply this to an accented word, Example:

```
"gonzález" = "GonzáLez",
"pérez" = "PéRez"
```

After an accented word there is a Uppercase letter again.

How can I modify the regular expression to avoid this issue?

hope you can help me!! :)

Comment: perhaps duplicate problem to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196972/convert-string-to-title-case-with-javascript/196991#196991 ?

Comment: @gillyspy: Doesn't support non-Latin characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\b` is a non word boundary (i.e `\b` would make a boundary for any any character which doesn't belong to any 1 of `[0-9a-zA-Z_]`)

So those accented word become the boundary for your word..

Instead use this regex

```
/(^|\s)[a-z\u00E0-\u00FC]/g
```

Comment: Hi I tried this in Chrome Javascript console and it says: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ^

Comment: @Anirudh: You'll still have the same problem. `[a-z]` won't match accented characters, so `él` will not get capitalized.

Answer (score 2):

`[a-z]` doesn't match `é`. You'll have to be a bit more lenient:

```
"gonzález foo bar, baz él".replace(/(^|\s)\S/g, function(match) {
    return match.toUpperCase();
});
```

And the output:

```
"González Foo Bar, Baz Él"
```

Comment: I would suggest improvement, so it can handle string like "stRING": "gonzález foo bar, baz él".toLowerCase().replace(...)