# Angular 2 typescript - capitalize each word in input

Tags: javascript, capitalize

I have an angular form like:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input
        matInput
        placeholder="Name">
</mat-form-field>
```

I need to capitalize each word in input. I used following code:

```
input.value = current.replace(/\b(\w)/g, symbol => symbol.toLocaleUpperCase());
```

but it doesn't capitalize characters like "ľščťžýáíé..." how can I solve this?

After inserting **"abcděf čdef"** it returns **"AbcděF čDef"** (just an example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED:

replaced original regex: **/\b(\w)/g** 
with new regex: **/(^|\s)[a-z\u00E0-\u170E]/g**

Answer (score 1):

\b is a non word boundary (i.e \b would make a boundary for any any character which doesn't belong to any 1 of [0-9a-zA-Z_])

So those accented word become the boundary for your word..

Instead use this regex

```
         /(^|\s)[a-z\u00E0-\u00FC]/g
```

Comment: you sure ?, check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573099/javascript-jquery-uppercase-first-letter-of-variable-with-accents

Comment: solved, chceck my answer, it didn't just accept characters after \u00FC