# Convert string to sentence case in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a string entered should be converted to sentence case in whatever case it is.

Like

> hi all, this is derp. thank you all to answer my query.

be converted to

> Hi all, this is derp. Thank you all to answer my query.

Comment: ...and? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Hint: Try writing a regular expression. Find the first letter of sentences and use periods+spaces to delimit sentences. Good luck. If you still need help after attempting the regex, post it here and we'll see what we can do.

Comment: Why do you go for javascript when you can do it with CSS?

Comment: NB: not all period characters indicate the end of a sentence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this, It will work fine for you. It will also work for **String having leading spaces**.

```
var string="hi all, this is derp. thank you all to answer my query.";
var n=string.split(".");
var vfinal=""
for(i=0;i<n.length;i++)
{
   var spaceput=""
   var spaceCount=n[i].replace(/^(\s*).*$/,"$1").length;
   n[i]=n[i].replace(/^\s+/,"");
   var newstring=n[i].charAt(n[i]).toUpperCase() + n[i].slice(1);
   for(j=0;j<spaceCount;j++)
   spaceput=spaceput+" ";
   vfinal=vfinal+spaceput+newstring+".";
 }
 vfinal=vfinal.substring(0, vfinal.length - 1);
 alert(vfinal);
```

Comment: great. this will work for leading space in a string.

Answer (score 22):

I came up with this kind of RegExp:

```
var rg = /(^\w{1}|\.\s*\w{1})/gi;
var myString = "hi all, this is derp. thank you all to answer my query.";
myString = myString.replace(rg, function(toReplace) {
    return toReplace.toUpperCase();
});
```

Comment: Ok, I'll add that one asterisk in there and it will.

Comment: but it will not work for space in starting of "    hi all,----" .you have to edit that too.

Comment: var rg = /(^\s*\w{1}|\.\s*\w{1})/gi;    It will work . please update.

Comment: I answered to the question that was originally posted. If OP wants to make specific changes to all possible cases (including typos etc.), he has to learn regular expressions himself. This answer was shortest availabe + it's demonstrating using variables inside regexps and looping them through in replace() function.

Answer (score 2):

## Here's my modification of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40111894/8262102) which was for changing to Title Case.

> You could immediately `toLowerCase` the string, and then just `toUpperCase` the first letter of each word. Becomes a very simple 1 liner:

Instead of making it every word. This example is compatible with multiple lines and strings like `A.M.` and `P.M.` and of course, any word proceeding a period and a whitespace character.

You could add your own custom words below that `toLowerCaseNames` function and `toUpperCaseNames` in that example below.

```js
// Based off this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40111894/8262102
var str = '-------------------\nhello world!\n\n2 Line Breaks. What is going on with this string. L.M.A.O.\n\nThee End...\nlower case example 1\nlower case example 2\n-------------------\nwait there\'s more!\n-------------------\nhi all, this is derp. thank you all to answer my query.';
function toTitleCase(str) {
 return str.toLowerCase().replace(/\.\s*([a-z])|^[a-z]/gm, s => s.toUpperCase());
}

// Add your own names here to override to lower case
function toLowerCaseNames(str) {
  return str.replace(/\b(lower case example 1|lower case example 2)\b/gmi, s => s.toLowerCase());
}

// Add your own names here to override to UPPER CASE
function toUpperCaseNames(str) {
  return str.replace(/\b(hello|string)\b/gmi, s => s.toUpperCase());
}

console.log(toLowerCaseNames(toUpperCaseNames(toTitleCase(str))));
```

---

You can paste all those regexp above into https://regexr.com/ to break down how they work.

Answer (score 1):

Try Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/devmgs/6hrv2/

```
function sentenceCase(strval){

 var newstrs = strval.split(".");
    var finalstr="";
    //alert(strval);
    for(var i=0;i<newstrs.length;i++)
        finalstr=finalstr+"."+ newstrs[i].substr(0,2).toUpperCase()+newstrs[i].substr(2);
    return finalstr.substr(1);
}
```

Beware all dot doesn't always represent end of line and may be abbreviations etc. Also its not sure if one types a space after the full stop. These conditions make this script vulnerable.

Answer (score 1):

The following SentenceCase code works fine for me and also handles abbreviations such e.g. a.m. and so on. May require improvements.

```js
//=============================
// SentenceCase Function
// Copes with abbreviations
// Mohsen Alyafei (12-05-2017)
//=============================

function stringSentenceCase(str) {
  return str.replace(/\.\s+([a-z])[^\.]|^(\s*[a-z])[^\.]/g, s => s.replace(/([a-z])/,s => s.toUpperCase()))
}
//=============================

console.log(stringSentenceCase(" start sentence.   second sentence . e.g. a.m. p.m."))
console.log(stringSentenceCase("first sentence. second sentence."))
console.log(stringSentenceCase("e.g. a.m. p.m. P.M. another sentence"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

```
<script>
var name="hi all, this is derp. thank you all to answer my query.";
var n = name.split(".");
var newname="";
for(var i=0;i<n.length;i++)
{
var j=0;
while(j<n[i].length)
{
if(n[i].charAt(j)!= " ")
    {
        n[i] = n[i].replace(n[i].charAt(j),n[i].charAt(j).toUpperCase());
            break;
    }
else
  j++;
}

newname = newname.concat(n[i]+".");
 }
alert(newname);
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I ended up using:

```
str = 'hi all, this is derp. thank you all to answer my query.';
temp_arr = str.split('.');
for (i = 0; i < temp_arr.length; i++) {
temp_arr[i]=temp_arr[i].trim()
temp_arr[i] = temp_arr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + temp_arr[i].substr(1).toLowerCase();
}
str=temp_arr.join('. ') + '.';
return str;
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code is working for me as expected.

```
   function toSentenceCase(inputString) {
        inputString = "." + inputString;
   var result = "";
   if (inputString.length == 0) {
       return result;
   }

   var terminalCharacterEncountered = false;
   var terminalCharacters = [".", "?", "!"];
   for (var i = 0; i < inputString.length; i++) {
       var currentChar = inputString.charAt(i);
       if (terminalCharacterEncountered) {
           if (currentChar == ' ') {
               result = result + currentChar;
           } else {
               var currentCharToUpperCase = currentChar.toUpperCase();
               result = result + currentCharToUpperCase;
               terminalCharacterEncountered = false;
           }
       } else {
           var currentCharToLowerCase = currentChar.toLowerCase();
           result = result + currentCharToLowerCase;
       }
       for (var j = 0; j < terminalCharacters.length; j++) {
           if (currentChar == terminalCharacters[j]) {
               terminalCharacterEncountered = true;
               break;
           }
       }
   }
        result = result.substring(1, result.length - 1);
   return result;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an FSM-based function to coalesce multiple whitespace characters and convert a string to sentence-case. It should be fast because it doesn't use complex regular-expression or `split` and assuming your JavaScript runtime has efficient string concatenation then this should be the fastest way to do it. It also lets you easily add special-case exceptions.

Performance can probably be improved further by replacing the whitespace regexs with a function to compare char-codes.

```js
function toSentenceCase(str) {

    var states = {
        EndOfSentence  : 0,
        EndOfSentenceWS: 1, // in whitespace immediately after end-of-sentence
        Whitespace     : 2,
        Word           : 3
    };

    var state = states.EndOfSentence;
    var start = 0;
    var end   = 0;

    var output = "";
    var word = "";

    function specialCaseWords(word) {
        if( word == "i" ) return "I";
        if( word == "assy" ) return "assembly";
        if( word == "Assy" ) return "Assembly";
        return word;
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {

        var c = str.charAt(i);

        switch( state ) {
            case states.EndOfSentence:

                if( /\s/.test( c ) ) { // if char is whitespace

                    output += " "; // append a single space character
                    state = states.EndOfSentenceWS;
                }
                else {
                    word += c.toLocaleUpperCase();
                    state = states.Word;
                }

                break;

            case states.EndOfSentenceWS:

                if( !( /\s/.test( c ) ) ) { // if char is NOT whitespace

                    word += c.toLocaleUpperCase();
                    state = states.Word;
                }

                break;
            case states.Whitespace:

                if( !( /\s/.test( c ) ) ) { // if char is NOT whitespace

                    output += " "; // add a single whitespace character at the end of the current whitespace region only if there is non-whitespace text after.
                    word += c.toLocaleLowerCase();
                    state = states.Word;
                }

                break;

            case states.Word:

                if( c == "." ) {

                    word = specialCaseWords( word );
                    output += word;
                    output += c;
                    word = "";
                    state = states.EndOfSentence;

                } else if( !( /\s/.test( c ) ) ) { // if char is NOT whitespace

                    // TODO: See if `c` is punctuation, and if so, call specialCaseWords(word) and then add the puncutation

                    word += c.toLocaleLowerCase();
                }
                else {
                    // char IS whitespace (e.g. at-end-of-word):

                    // look at the word we just reconstituted and see if it needs any special rules
                    word = specialCaseWords( word );
                    output += word;
                    word = "";

                    state = states.Whitespace;
                }

                break;
        }//switch
    }//for

    output += word;

    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On each line this script will print ..... Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday.

```
let rg = /(^\w{1}|\.\s*\w{1})/gi;

const days = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday'];

for(let day of days) {
    console.log(day.replace(rg, function(toReplace) {
    return toReplace.toUpperCase();
}))
```

Comment: On each line It will print ..... 
Sunday
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday
Friday
Saturday

Comment: Why don't you add the clarification for your answer in the answer itself instead of as a comment?

Answer (score 0):

```
function toTitleCase(str) {
  if (!str) return "";
  return str
    .replace(/(?:^\w|[A-Z]|\b\w)/g, function (word, index) {
      return index === 0 ? word.toUpperCase() : word.toLowerCase();
    })
    .replace(/\s+/g, "");
}
```

Comment: Can you please add some context and explanation to this answer thanks.