# Convert string to title case in Coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

I know there's a [javascript solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/196991/691859) for this problem, but how can I do this in Coffeescript? e.g. "HELLO" -> "Hello".

I have this so far, but I'm not sure on how to make it work for multiple words:

```
titleCase = (str) ->
    str[0].toUpperCase() + str[1..str.length-1].toLowerCase()
```

Comment: Coffeescript is javascript. It would be the exact same, just in coffeescript.

Comment: @Fresheyeball I'm new to Coffeescript, so I wasn't able to obviously see the conversion. I am aware of this, though.

Comment: @Fresheyeball While it's true that coffeescript is javascript, it's often possible to write something more concise than a 1-to-1 translation in coffeescript by making use of its idioms. For instance, it's possible to reduce `str[1..str.length-1]` to `str[1..-1]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be an almost 1:1 conversion from your linked answer.

```
toTitleCase = (str) ->
    str.replace /\w\S*/g, (txt) -> # see comment below
        txt[0].toUpperCase() + txt[1..txt.length - 1].toLowerCase()
```

The second line uses the regex version of replace - any occurrence of letters followed by a space will be matched and replaced with the result of calling the following function with the matched string.

Comment: Shoot, I was thinking CoffeeScript had the same functions in Ruby! I was using `.upcase` and `.downcase`!