# Format lowercased string to capitalize the begining of each sentence

Tags: javascript, regex, string, lowercase, capitalization

I have a string like

`FIRST SENTENCE. SECOND SENTENCE.`

I want to *lowercase* the string in that way to capitalize the first letter of each sentence.

For example:

```
string = string.toLowerCase().capitalize();
```

only the first sentence is capitalized.

I have the

String.prototype.capitalize = function() {
        return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);
    }

function

Does anyone know how to solve?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you only want to capitalize the first word of each sentence (not every word), then use this function:

```
function applySentenceCase(str) {
    return str.replace(/.+?[\.\?\!](\s|$)/g, function (txt) {
        return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
    });
}
```

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/VAKk8/)

If you want to keep the formatting of the rest of the sentence and just capitalize the first letters, change `txt.substr(1).toLowerCase()` to `txt.substr(1)`

Comment: And what is tha difference if I use replace(/\w\S*/g, function (txt) instead of your code? Thank you.

Comment: @zsola3075457 That would put a capital letter at the beginning of *every* word: http://jsfiddle.net/VAKk8/1/

Comment: Use `/.+?([\.\?\!]\s|$)/g` to make it work for single/ending sentences without punctuation as well

Comment: function applySentenceCase(str) {
    return str.toLowerCase().replace(/(^.|\.\s.|\!\s.|\?\s.)/g, function (txt) {
        return txt.toUpperCase();
    });
}

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
function toTitleCase(str) {
    return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function (txt) {
        return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
    });
}

alert(toTitleCase('FIRST SENTENCE. SECOND SENTENCE.'))
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8rYmw/)</kbd>

With [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196972/convert-string-to-title-case-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

This JS function will apply sentence case to the initial sentence and any sentences that follow a sentence that ends with . ? !

```js
function applySentenceCase(str) {
    var txt = str.split(/(.+?[\.\?\!](\s|$))/g);
    for (i = 0; i < (txt.length-1); i++) {
        if (txt[i].length>1){
            txt[i]=txt[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt[i].substr(1).toLowerCase();
        } else if (txt[i].length==1) {
            txt[i]=txt[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase();
        }
    }
    txt = txt.join('').replace(/\s\s/g,' ');
    return txt;
}

alert(applySentenceCase("LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET, CONSECTETUR ADIPISCING ELIT. sed congue hendrerit risus, ac viverra magna elementum in. InTeRdUm Et MaLeSuAdA fAmEs Ac AnTe IpSuM pRiMiS iN fAuCiBuS. phasellus EST purus, COMMODO vitae IMPERDIET eget, ORNARE quis ELIT."));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you

```
<a style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="capitaliseFirstLetter('hey wassup baby')">asd</a>

<div type="text" id="texts"></div>
```

Javascript

```
    function capitaliseFirstLetter(string)
{
    var array = string.split(" ");
    for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        var n = array[i];
        var a = n.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + n.slice(1);
        alert(a);
    }

}
```

visit : http://jsfiddle.net/rVnFU/

Comment: Sorry, I have forgot, but I already have this function, this capitalize only the first sentence.