# How to enable autocapitalization for contenteditable elements on mobile

Tags: html, input, mobile, contenteditable, autocapitalize

I have a contenteditable div where users can post comments:

```
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

However, when you type in this field on a mobile phone, it does not autocapitalize the first letter after a sentence.

On mobile, it should capitalize the first letter after each sentence ends. So:

> "This is a sentence. Now, the word 'now' should be capitalized"

I know that this may only be a feature for input fields, but is there a way to achieve/hack this on a contenteditable element?

Comment: Are you able to use JS? Or this is an HTML/CSS only question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20441876/format-lowercased-string-to-capitalize-the-begining-of-each-sentence

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy JS is ok, since I realized there is not really a HTML solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I realized that since im using Emojionearea, autocapitalize was not working. So it's my own fault for not initializing Emojionearea with autocapitalize.

I apologize for leaving this detail behind. Maybe this question will help others that are also using Emojionearea.

Correct code should be:

**Html**

```
 <div id='textField' contenteditable="true" ></div>
```

**JS**

```
 $('#textField').emojioneArea({
                placeholder: $(this).data("placeholder"),
                pickerPosition: "bottom",
                attributes: {
                    spellcheck: true,
                    autocapitalize: "on"
                }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking for a HTML/CSS answer, the Autocapitalise global attribute is what you want. Setting Autocapitalise to either "on" or "sentences" will capitalize the first letter of each sentence.
Here is an example:

```
<input type="text" autocapitalise="on" />
```

Comment: This is exactly what the OP said is not working, what did your answer add?

Comment: The autocapitalize attribute is [not a standard attribute and is not supported by most browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-html_elements_form_autocapitalize). It only would work in iOS Safari...