# Rhino JavaScript Method of Replacing Character & TitleCase

Tags: javascript, string, replace, rhino

I need to convert Paid Search terms into a normal sentence case string.  For example, the Google referring URL would contain the following:

**q=javascript+stackoverlow+HELP**

My current code escapes the value, but I'm thinking I need a simple function to remove the plus signs and set the case properly so that it looks like this:

**Javascript Stackoverflow Help**

Here is my current setup.

```
if (landing.referrer.domain.match(/google\.com/)) {
  return unescape(landing.referrer.param('q'));
} else if (landing.referrer.domain.match(/yahoo\.com/)) {
  return unescape(landing.referrer.param('p')); 
} else if (landing.referrer.domain.match(/bing\.com/)) {
  return unescape(landing.referrer.param('q'));  
}
```

I only need to worry about English (Latin) character set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use:

```
if (!String.prototype.toTitleCase) {
    String.prototype.toTitleCase = function() {
        return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.substring(1).toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

And:

```
function getSearchTerms(link) {
    link = link.substring(link.indexOf("=") + 1);

    var arr = link.split("+");
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = arr[i].toTitleCase();
    }

    return arr.join(" ");
}
```

[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3G6AW/)

Answer (score 1):

To replace

```
var string = '+';
var re = new RegExp(find, 'g');

str = str.replace(re, '');
```

Title case

```
function toTitleCase(str)
{
    return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
}
```

Ref : [Convert string to title case with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196972/convert-string-to-title-case-with-javascript)

Answer (score -1):

You can just use css inside JavaScript. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44962866/3674573).

The full code can be:

```
function format_str(str) {
    formatted_str = str.replace(/+/g, ' ');
    return '<span style="text-transform: capitalize">'+ formatted_str +'</span>';
}
```