# Convert string to title case not working, and populate div tag with input string all javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have been struggling with the following code. Basically I took the example [Convert string to title case with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196972/convert-string-to-title-case-with-javascript/196991#196991) and am using that, I also have a code which takes the name and populates it into a div tag, however, it seems to move the text down, so for example when I type in **john smith**, I don't get **John Smith** for the capatalisation and then where it states **'s fathers full name** it does place the name there but then moves the rest of that text one line down, so **'s fathers full name** moves one line below **john smith**, can someone help me figure this out?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en-GB">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>hello whirled</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Bla Bla
    </h1>
    <form name="input" action="submit.php" method="post">
        <p>
            Other Text goes here
        </p>
        <p>
            How do you wish to be referred to informally?
             <input id="name1" type="text" name="groominame" onchange="toTitleCase(this.value); fathersName(this.value);" />
        </p>
        <div id="display1"></div>
        's full name:
        <input type="text" name="fname" />
        <noscript>
            <div>
                If you can see this then SCRIPTS are turned OFF on your machine and it won't work 
            </div>
        </noscript>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function toTitleCase(str) {
                alert(str); //test
                return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function (txt) {
                    return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
                });
            }

            function fathersName(textarea) {
                alert(textarea); //test
                document.getElementById("display1").innerHTML = textarea;
            }

        </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your JavaScript syntax doesn't work at all...

Comment: I know a simple JQuery code for this, you prefer that?

Comment: You are not doing anything with the return value of `toTitleCase`. You are converting the input somehow, but you are not using the output.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean Alexandre? The Fathers name works on my PC and it does replace the text in the DIV box, but I can't get it to capitalise.

Comment: Ah I see @FelixKling King, I have to place the input into the output. I have changed the text to `toTitleCase` so instead of `return str...` I have `var name = str...` and then added `document.getElementById("name1").innerHTML = name;` but it doesn't seem to populate that input field name1.

Comment: @Dino Maybe you should try `document.getElementById("name1").value = name;`

Comment: I use the `.value` and it worked @Akshay Takkar and I also used @mohamedrias however I see that I might have a lot of functions for similar code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="display1" style="float: left;margin: 3px 0px;"></div>
```

The above code will make it align properly with the text `'s full name`.

Your function is not working properly and also two functions are not needed.

```
function fathersName(ele) {
    var textarea = toTitleCase(ele);
    document.getElementById("display1").innerHTML = textarea;
}

function toTitleCase(ele) {
    var str = ele.value;
    ele.value = str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function (txt) {
        return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
    });
    return ele.value;
}
```

so input tag changes to

```
 <input id="name1" type="text" name="groominame" onChange=" fathersName(this);"/>
```

If you just want to use toTitleCase in other fields, then use `toTitleCase(this)`

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/nabob/1/edit)**

Comment: I need the field that was input to also change to uppercase once they leave the input field. So that is why I had them in a separate function.

Comment: So mohamedrias when I try the same function above to populate the input field it doesn't do it. Do you know why?

Comment: I have updated the answer, no need of two functions still :) http://jsbin.com/nabob/2/edit

Comment: Instead of passing this.value, you need to pass only this in fathersName(this);

Comment: I see, but I do need these functions to be separate as I use the convert to upper case on other input values. So for example I have another field called Brides Name so that needs to automatically be capitalised (first part of names) once they leave that field. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first turn it into Upper case and then display it. You just return it to nowhere instead of keeping it in a variable or placing it in the right place.
The div moves because at the end of a div there is a new line, if you want there not to be an effect use a span element.