# Is there a method for spaces in cases in js?

Tags: javascript

the question is there is a method such as .toUpperCase() which recognises that there might be spaces between the strings in different cases. I researched on it however couldn't find one. This is what I want to implement. It was one of the exercises on the code academy.

```
var movie = prompt("movie please").toUpperCase();
var getReview = function (movie) {
switch(movie){
    //case 'Toy Story 2':
        //console.log("Great Story. Mean prospector.");
        //break;
    //case 'Finding Nemo':
        console.log("Cool animation, and funny turtles.");
        break;
    case 'The Lion King':
        console.log("Great songs.");
        break;
    default:
        console.log("I don't know!");
}
```

};

I passed the exercise using a different code but I just wanted to ask out of curiousity.

Answer (score 2):

You could remove all spaces:

```
movie = prompt("movie please").toUpperCase().replace(/\s/g,"");
switch(movie) {
    case "TOYSTORY2":
       // ....
    case "THELIONKING":
    case "LIONKING": // allow not having "the" as well
       // ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about title case? see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196972/convert-string-to-title-case-with-javascript)

```
function toTitleCase(str)
{
    return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){
        return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
    });
}
```