# Convert cities to make first letter to uppercase. if I have new york I want it New York

Tags: javascript

I'm using this code:

```
     function ucfirst(field) {
       field.value = field.value.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() +       field.value.substr(1);
}
```

this is working if i have a city like `california` ==> `California`. But if I have `new york` it will not convert the first letter.

Any tips how to make this code work?

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a JavaScript function, here's one from [Greg Dean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/196991/5177017)

```
function ucfirst(field)
{
    var fieldString = field.value;
    fieldString = fieldString.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
    field.value = fieldString;
}
```

Edit: Added Fievel Yaltsen's suggestion to use field.value instead of return.

And here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/og31yca9/)

Comment: @doudy_05 In your case, you may want to replace 'return' with 'field.value ='

Comment: @doudy_05 how about now?

Comment: I receive this error message: 
Uncaught TypeError: field.replace is not a function

Comment: I have a field when I type new york I need to convert the first letters and this code is giving me this error>
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Comment: @doudy_05 ok, try it now.

Comment: @abagh0703 perfect! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why javascript if you can do it with css?

```css
p {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<p>california, new york</p>
```

Comment: It's simple but there is no tag related CSS...

Comment: Because he asked for Javascript? What if this was a node.js app?

Answer (score 0):

```
function ucfirst(str)
{
    return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
}
```

Comment: when I use this code I have this error
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
p.capitalize {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p class="capitalize">This is some text.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.