# Converting lowercase character for every word to uppercase javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, uppercase, lowercase

I am writng a javascript for converting first character of every word to uppercase.
My Javascript code is..

```
<script>
    var param1var = "<?php echo $_REQUEST['from']; ?>"
    var param2var = "<?php echo $_REQUEST['to']; ?>"

    window.onload = function displayresult() {
        if (param1var != '') {

            document.getElementById("movefromid").value = param1var;
            document.getElementById("movetoid").value = param2var;
        } else if (param2var != '') {
            document.getElementById("movefromid").value = 'UK';
            document.getElementById("movetoid").value = param2var;
        }
    }
</script>
```

here param1var and param2var are two variables having values from 2 querystring variables.
this javascript is written for auto selecting option in select box through query string..
Now for example the value for param1var= india.. then i want it to convert it into param1var= India before it is setting in select box. and Same for param2var. 
Any suggestion for doing this..

Comment: @Tushar please put this in my code snippet.

Comment: try without js `text-transform: capitalize;` http://jsfiddle.net/nfgpe738/

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196972/convert-string-to-title-case-with-javascript

Comment: document.getElementById("movefromid").value ==param1var.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + param1var.slice(1);        document.getElementById("movetoid").value ==param2var.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + param2var.slice(1);