# Document title pulling in dynamic keywords will not change casing on first letter of words

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been looking around for answer to this but haven't found solution that works for my situation. I'm pulling in keywords dynamically from the URL and populating the page title with them. They are lower case and I need to find a way to make the first letter of each keyword Uppercase. This is the script I have so far:

```js
var keywords = window.location.href.match(/kw=(.+)/)[1];

var array = keywords.split('+');

document.title = array.join("" + " ");
```

I thought this would be so simple but have struggled with it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Update: this works

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var metas = document.getElementsByTagName('meta'); 

   for (var i=0; i<metas.length; i++) { 
  if (metas[i].getAttribute("property") == "keywords") { 
    document.title = metas[i].getAttribute("content") + " "; 
  } 
   } 
   
 var mystr = document.title;
 var subs =  mystr.replace(",", " ");
 var newtitle = toTitleCase(subs);
 document.title = newtitle;


 function toTitleCase(str) {
   return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt) {
     return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
   });
 } 

  </script>
```

Comment: str.toUpperCase();

Comment: @RachelGallen wouldn't that make the entire string upper case instead of just the first letter?

Comment: @BabakNaffas yes, i misread the question http://stackoverflow.com/a/196991/1675954 here's the best answer

Comment: @shepherdMan1016 no bother happy to help :)

Comment: Can you put the code in your question? Edit it. Can't read it as a comment!

Comment: Still a comment! Edit your QUESTION

Comment: @RachelGallen - My apologies and thank you. I've updated the questions. Please help if you are able. My sincere thanks.

Comment: @shepherdMan1016 try that.. but i have to warn you its 23:20 irish time so no more updates tonight!

Comment: @shepherdMan1016 this script will capitalize the first letter of each word - is that what you want? Otherwise what you need is sentence case not title case rachelgallen.com/test7.html  (i edited the script a few hours ago.. in the early hours of the morning here!)

Comment: Thanks @RachelGallen. I was able to figure this out last night. You got me going in the right direction. Many thanks! You're the best.