# Lodash title case (uppercase first letter of every word)

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm looking through the lodash docs and other Stack Overflow questions - while there [are several native JavaScript ways of accomplishing this task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196972/convert-string-to-title-case-with-javascript), is there a way I can convert a string to title case using *purely* lodash functions (or at least existing prototypal functions) so that I don't have to use a regular expression or define a new function?

e.g.

```
This string ShouLD be ALL in title CASe
```

should become

```
This String Should Be All In Title Case
```

Comment: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/1528

Comment: you can do same thing from HTML also, **style="text-transform: capitalize"**

Comment: The reason why this doesn't exist in `lodash` is because different use cases expect different results from it. When `titleCase`-ing french names (e.g: `jean-pierre`), the expected result is `Jean-Pierre`. But when `titleCase`-ing npm package names, the expected result from `some-package-name` is `Some Package Name`.

Comment: Since `lodash` doesn't offer a good solution because of special characters issue, here's another ready to use package for that: `titleCase(str.toLowerCase())` from https://www.npmjs.com/package/title-case . Tis properly handles special characters and capitalization after `-` and `'`

Answer (score 329, accepted):

This can be done with a small modification of [`startCase`](https://lodash.com/docs#startCase):

```
_.startCase(_.toLower(str));
```

```js
console.log(_.startCase(_.toLower("This string ShouLD be ALL in title CASe")));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `_.startCase("aaa BBB ccc") === "Aaa BBB Ccc"`

Comment: @Brandon How about now?

Comment: I like it.  I didn't know about `startCase`.

Comment: _.startCase("camelString")  === "Camel String"
but 
_.startCase(_.toLower("camelString"))  === "Camelstring"

seems like lodash needs a titleCase method

Comment: @aristidesfl To handle the situation where the input was camelCase, you would need to run it through [`_.lowerCase`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#lowerCase) first instead of `_.toLower`. But yeah, it's too bad there isn't a function that just goes straight to it.

Comment: @aristidesfl But it would break the string `'This string ShouLD be ALL in title CASe'` so I didn't do it. Since `ShouLD` would become `Shou L D`

Comment: @4castle true. however I suspect that in most situations where you want to display title case, you don't start with random CrAzY CaSE. Most often one wants to convert from other type of case, and the suggested method handles those better (upper, camel, pascal, snake) http://stackoverflow.com/a/39510222/1445812

Comment: @aristidesfl Right, but this question is about a CrAzY CaSE, so that answer does not answer the question.

Comment: @4castle even though the question is not specifically about CraZy CaSE, the provided example is CrAzY CaSE, so fair enough. Can't get tired of typing in CrAzY CaSE.

Comment: I like this, however, it removes characters such as `:`, that is a problem.

Comment: It does not work for first names with accent (Spanish "Martínez Cortés Peña" becomes "Martinez Cortes Pena") or with hyphens (French "Jean-Louis" becomes "Jean Louis"). Same goes for any "*Case" functions of lodash

Comment: We should avoid _ imports (import _ from 'lodash'`) this simply passes a bad practice to people

Comment: This will work for the example in the question however, it's important to note that it removes special characters like underscores and hyphens from the string.

Comment: this is not title case /: words like "the" get capitalized to "The".

Comment: @JohnMiller Title case has many different definitions. See the various rules here: https://capitalizemytitle.com/#capitalizationrules The OP specified they just want to uppercase the first letter of every word.

Answer (score 77):

```
_.startCase(_.camelCase(str))
```

For non-user-generated text, this handles more cases than the accepted answer

```
> startCase(camelCase('myString'))
'My String'
> startCase(camelCase('my_string'))
'My String'
> startCase(camelCase('MY_STRING'))
'My String'
> startCase(camelCase('my string'))
'My String'
> startCase(camelCase('My string'))
'My String'
```

Comment: equivalent to `_.startCase(_.lowerCase(string))`

Comment: `camelCase` stomped on by the `startCase`, it's no longer a camel.

Answer (score 49):

with lodash version 4.

`_.upperFirst(_.toLower(str))`

Comment: This one is better than `startCase` because it can handle more letters than a-z, for example å, ä and ö.

Comment: upperFirst will only change the first word's first character, not for subsequent words. I don't believe this is better than startCase for this particular reason.

Comment: Finally a correct answer!

Answer (score 34):

```
'This string ShouLD be ALL in title CASe'
  .split(' ')
  .map(_.capitalize)
  .join(' ');
```

Comment: Definitely the most concise, like it. Obviously still requires splitting into an array, but that's still the shortest and sweetest solution from what I can tell. Also, per the issue 1528 that @AlexandreThebaldi indicated, probably should use `upperFirst` instead of `capitalize`.

Comment: ... but _.startCase definitely wins :)

Comment: `_.startCase` removes punctuation. Example `_.startCase('first second etc...` returns the string `First Second Etc`

Comment: This was better for my use case as `startCase` converts everything to a blank for example `user_name` will be `User Name`, and i only wanted `User_name` like the `text-transform: capitalize` property of CSS

Answer (score 19):

There are mixed answers to this question.
Some are recommending using `_.upperFirst` while some recommending `_.startCase`.

Know the difference between them.

i) `_.upperFirst` will transform the first letter of your string, then string might be of a single word or multiple words but the only first letter of your string is transformed to uppercase.

`_.upperFirst('jon doe')`

output:

`Jon doe`

check the documentation https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#upperFirst

ii) `_.startCase` will transform the first letter of every word inside your string.

`_.startCase('jon doe')`

output:

`Jon Doe`

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#startCase

Comment: Yep, but what about mixed case strings? Neither of these will make ‘jOn DoE’ into ‘Jon Doe’ without `_.lower()`.

Answer (score 7):

That's the cleanest & most flexible implementation imo from testing it on my own use cases.

```js
import { capitalize, map } from "lodash";

const titleCase = (str) => map(str.split(" "), capitalize).join(" ");

// titleCase("ALFRED NÚÑEZ") => "Alfred Núñez"
// titleCase("alfred núñez") => "Alfred Núñez"
// titleCase("AlFReD nÚñEZ") => "Alfred Núñez"
// titleCase("-") => "-"
```

Answer (score 5):

Below code will work perfectly:

```
var str = "TITLECASE";
_.startCase(str.toLowerCase());
```

Answer (score 4):

From https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/3383#issuecomment-430586750

```
'JHON&JOHN C/O DR. BLah'.replace(/\w+/g, _.capitalize);
```

result:

```
'Jhon&John C/O Dr. Blah'
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way using ONLY lodash methods and no builtin methods:

```
_.reduce(_.map(_.split("Hello everyOne IN the WOrld", " "), _.capitalize), (a, b) => a + " " + b)
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with only lodash

```
properCase = string =>
        words(string)
            .map(capitalize)
            .join(' ');

const proper = properCase('make this sentence propercase');

console.log(proper);
//would return 'Make This Sentence Propercase'
```

Comment: You need to require capitalize and words from lodash.

Comment: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#words

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#capitalize

Comment: Yes, but you’re not calling the functions from lodash; unless you’ve aliased them somehow `var words = ._words`

Answer (score 1):

```
 var s = 'This string ShouLD be ALL in title CASe';
 _.map(s.split(' '), (w) => _.capitalize(w.toLowerCase())).join(' ')
```

Unless i missed it, lodash doesnt have its own lower/upper case methods.

Comment: @vbotio looks like `_.upperFirst` only applies to the first character (a synonym for `_.capitalize()`?)

Comment: `capitalize` and `upperFirst` do different things.

Comment: _.capitalize applies to the entire string

Answer (score 1):

```
const titleCase = str =>
  str
    .split(' ')
    .map(str => {
      const word = str.toLowerCase()
      return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1)
    })
    .join(' ')
```

You can also split out the map function to do separate words

Answer (score 0):

Not as concise as @4castle's answer, but descriptive and lodash-full, nonetheless...

```js
var basicTitleCase = _
    .chain('This string ShouLD be ALL in title CASe')
    .toLower()
    .words()
    .map(_.capitalize)
    .join(' ')
    .value()

console.log('Result:', basicTitleCase)
console.log('Exact Match:' , basicTitleCase === 'This String Should Be All In Title Case')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'd guess that the verbosity and length of the answer makes it almost undesirable. I didn't downvote, but it wouldn't be my first choice.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution for my use case:
"devil's backbone"

Simply:

```
function titleCase (str) {
  return _.map(str.split(' '), _.upperFirst).join(' ');
}
```

Using startCase would remove the apostrophe, so I had to work around that limitation. The other solutions seemed pretty convoluted. I like this as it's clean, easy to understand.

Comment: This, however, fails to titleCase a string that has all uppercase letters.

Answer (score -3):

you can simply use the lowdash capitalize methode , it Converts the first character of string to upper case and the remaining to lower case.
https://lodash.com/docs/#capitalize

```
const str = 'titlecase this string ';
_.capitalize(str); //Titlecase This String
```

Comment: No, this doesn't work for already uppercased letters.

Answer (score -4):

with lodash 4, you can use _.capitalize()

`_.capitalize('JOHN')`
It returns 'John'

See https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#capitalize for details

Comment: Would be good to test the use case for a sentence of words. Suspect this does not capitalize all the first letters of each word.

Comment: Indeed, 'the sentence' outputs 'The sentence'