# How do I make a function that capitalizes letters both at the beginning of a person's first name, as well as their last in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var fullnames =["george bush","barrack obama","donald trump"]
```

and return

```
var fullNames =["George Bush","Barrack Obama","Donald Trump"]
```

Comment: What about `George walker bush`?

Comment: Have you tried anything to solve the problem yourself?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string to title case with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196972/convert-string-to-title-case-with-javascript)

Comment: Explode each string individually using space as a delimiter, make the first letter caps for each of the new strings and recombine. Also dupe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
["george bush","barrack obama","donald trump"].map(function(name){return name.replace(/\b\w/g, function(firstLetter){return firstLetter.toUpperCase()})})
```