# jQuery Convert Sentence Case

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got some JavaScript running a convert case on some text:

```
$(".container").click(function(){
  text = text.toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function(block){
  return block.toUpperCase();
});
```

Which returns given text in the container div to Sentence Case. However when an apostrophe is used in the text, such as

```
can't get this to work
```

it returns

```
Can'T Get This To Work
```

How can I make that trailing t after the apostrophe stay lowercase?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string to title case with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196972/convert-string-to-title-case-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your expression isn't working is because a [word boundary, `\b`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-word-boundary), is short for `(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)`, and that doesn't include `'` characters which means that the character after `'`, in your case it was `t`, was being selected.

You could replace `\b` with `(^|\s)`, which would be `/(^|\s)[a-z]/g`, and that would work in your case:

```
$(".container").click(function() {
  text = text.toLowerCase().replace(/(^|\s)[a-z]/g, function(block) {
    return block.toUpperCase();
  });
});
```

---

However, the best approach would be to use the regular expression `\w\S*`, which will select any word characters (i.e., `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) followed by any non string character (i.e., `[^\r\n\t\f ]`).

This will allow you to select each word substring. From there you can capitalize the first character and convert the remaining characters to lowercase:

```
$(".container").click(function() {
  text = text.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(word) {
    return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.substr(1).toLowerCase();
  });
});
```

For instance, the following snippet would return:

```
"can't get this to work".replace(/\w\S*/g, function(word) {
  return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.substr(1).toLowerCase();
});

// > "Can't Get This To Work"
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed!