# Javascript Create Sentence Case Converter with Exceptions

Tags: javascript, string, function, sentencecase

I currently have a function that converts a string to sentence case.

```
 function toSentenceCase(str){
 convertedTextValueDesc = str.replace(/(^\w{1}|\.\s*\w{1})/gi);
```

}

This piece of code using RegEx doesn't convert ALL CAPITAL words to sentence case or allow for exceptions. Any help will be much appreciated and Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/196991/6048928

Comment: Try `str.toLowerCase().replace(...)`