# capitalize first letter of every capital words

Tags: javascript

If for a single capital word I know how to do that but for multiple capital word not sure how to do that.

single word: value.toLowerCase().charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.toLowerCase().slice(1);

It will change "DONE" to "Done"
But if I have "DONE DEAL" it changing to "Done deal" but it should like "Done Deal"

Comment: so split on words and loop or use a regular expression

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string to title case with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196972/convert-string-to-title-case-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `split` method in order to apply the rule for every work in sentence.

```js
var str="done done";
console.log(str.split(' ').map(function(item){
  return item.toLowerCase().charAt(0).toUpperCase() + item.toLowerCase().slice(1);
}).join(' '))
```

Comment: Thank u..perfect answer @alexandru

Answer (score 0):

Could do

```
    String line = "DONE DEAL";
    String[] words = line.split("\\s");
    for(String eachWord: words){
        String concat = eachWord.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase().concat(eachWord.substring(1).toLowerCase());
        System.out.println(concat);
    }
```

Comment: Anlexandru is the 1st one...Thanks for the help though