# Capitalizing first letter of each word, \b\w also applies to I'm

Tags: javascript, regex

Need to capitalize the first letter of each word in a sentence, my regex expression however is also capitalizing the 'm' in I'm.

The full expression is this:

```
/(?:^\w|[A-Z]|\b\w)/g
```

The problem here (I think) is that `\b\w` will grab the first letter after a word boundary. I'm assuming that single quotes denote a word boundary therefore also capitalizing the `m` of `I'm` into `I'M`.

Can anyone help me change the expression to exclude the 'm' after the single quotes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it JavaScript? Try `.replace(/('\w)|\b\w/g, function($0,$1) { return $1 ? $1 : $0.toLocaleUpperCase(); })`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes sir!

Comment: Why are you trying to use regex for this?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you Wiktor it works!

Comment: @cricket_007 I thought regex would be the most efficient and "beautiful" solution although I could be wrong, what do you suggest?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196972/convert-string-to-title-case-with-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding a real word break in the middle of language might be a bit more
complicated than using regex word boundary's.

```
 ( \s* [\W_]* )           # (1), Not letters/numbers,
 ( [^\W_] )               # (2), Followed by letter/number
 (                        # (3 start)
      (?:                      # -----------
           \w                       # Letter/number or _
        |                         # or,
           [[:punct:]_-]            # Punctuation
           (?= [\w[:punct:]-] )     #  if followed by punctuation/letter/number or '-'
        |                         #or,
           [?.!]                    # (Add) Special word ending punctuation
      )*                       # ----------- 0 to many times
 )                        # (3 end)
```

```js
var str = 'This "is the ,input _str,ng, the End ';
console.log(str);
console.log(str.replace(/(\s*[\W_]*)([^\W_])((?:\w|[[:punct:]_-](?=[\w[:punct:]-])|[?.!])*)/g, function( match, p1,p2,p3) {return p1 + p2.toUpperCase() + p3;}));
```

Comment: The Unicode version `\s*([^\pL\pN]*[\pL\pN](?:[\pL\pN_-]|\pP(?=[\pL\pN\pP_-])|[?.!])*)`