# For Loop Only Running Through Once

Tags: javascript, html

In the following program, for some reason, the for loop runs through once, and then does not repeat. I believe the error is with the bold code. Help is very much appreciated. This is a program used to change a text box to caps, title case, etc. Title case being the first letter of each word capitalized. Thank you.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function titlize(){
        tLength=tBox.box.value.length
        character=new Array()
        for(i=1; i<tLength+1; i++){
            **character[i]=tBox.box.value.slice(i-1,i)**
            document.write(character[i])
                if(i==1){
                character[i]=character[i].toUpperCase()
                }else if(character[i-1]==" "){
            character[i]=character[i].toUpperCase()
                }else{
            character[i]=character[i].toLowerCase()
            }
            document.write(i)
            document.write(character[i])
        }
    }

    function upperC (){
        toUpperCase(tBox.box.value)
    }

    function verify (){
        if(tBox.uppercase.checked){
        tBox.box.value=tBox.box.value.toUpperCase()
        }
        if(tBox.lowercase.checked){
        tBox.box.value=tBox.box.value.toLowerCase()
        }
        if(tBox.titlecase.checked){
        titlize()
        }
        if(tBox.uppercase.checked){
        tBox.box.value=tBox.box.value.toUpperCase()
        }

    }

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form name="tBox">
    <input type="text" name="box" value=""><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="uppercase" onClick=verify(this.form)>Uppercase<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="lowercase" onClick=verify(this.form)>Lowercase<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="titlecase" onClick=verify(this.form)>Titlecase<br>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196972/convert-string-to-title-case-with-javascript
function toTitleCase(str) {
    return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt) { return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase(); });
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tBox` is your `form` not your textbox, so trying to get it's value and then the length of that value is not valid. The code needs to access your textbox, so it should be:

```
   // Scan for the first textbox. Give that textbox a unique id to be 
   // able to write a more specific query.
   tLength= document.querySelector("input[type='text']").value.length;

   character=new Array()

   // Not sure why you were writing: i < tLength +1 as that will
   // cause your loop to go one character too far. Remember, 
   // arrays start from 0 and length starts from 1.
   for(i=1; i < tLength; i++){
```

Lastly, avoid `document.write()` because if you use it on a document that has finished being parsed, it will cause the entire existing document to be thrown out.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code above.  You have `document.write` statements in your function, which is causing issues in overwriting your `DOM`.  I've removed those, and that will allow it to function normally.  Also, I added `tBox.box.value = character.join("")` to put the text back into the text box.

https://plnkr.co/edit/qOPIxwH16hJUlj0RFBhv?p=preview

```
function titlize() {
    tLength=tBox.box.value.length;
    character=new Array();

    for(i=1; i < tLength + 1; i++){
        console.log('print')
        character[i]= tBox.box.value.slice(i - 1,i)
        //document.write(character[i])
            if(i==1) {
                character[i]=character[i].toUpperCase()
            } else if(character[i-1]==" ") {
                 character[i] = character[i].toUpperCase()
            } else {
                 character[i]=character[i].toLowerCase()
            }
        console.log(i)
        console.log(character[i])
    }

    tBox.box.value = character.join("")
}
```