# Regular Expressions, Length check in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to validate my form now, and I wrote some code, it's working perfectly for length constraints but I want to use Regular Expression to filter the values of each element.

I found from a forum, these Regular Expressions:

- for Full Name: `var regex = /^[a-zA-Z ]$/;`
- for Phone: `var regexPhone= /^[(]{0,1}[0-9]{3}[)]{0,1}[-\s\.]{0,1}[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]{0,1}[0-9]{4}$/;`

I guess the HTML5 (input:type email) is enough for email validation

Also I want to do this with the name, that when I type the full name, the first letters change to uppercase letters. For example--> input="john smith", changes to "John Smith".

This is my code:

```js
function validateForm() {
for (var i = 0; i < document.forms[0].elements.length; i++) {
    var pedio = document.forms[0].elements[i];
 if(pedio.id.indexOf("Name")!=-1){
  if (pedio.value.length < 5 || pedio.value.length > 35) {
   alert("Full Name must be 5-35 character long");
            pedio.focus();
            pedio.style.backgroundColor = "#997379";
            return false;
  }
 }
 
    if ((pedio.id.indexOf("Phone") != -1) && (isNaN(pedio.value))) {
        alert("Phone is must contain only numbers");
        pedio.focus();
        pedio.style.backgroundColor = "#997379";
        return false;
    }
 
 if(pedio.id.indexOf("Phone")!=-1){
  if (pedio.value.length!=10) {
   alert("Phone must be 10 numbers");
            pedio.focus();
            pedio.style.backgroundColor = "#997379";
            return false;
   }
  }
 }
}
```

```css
/* No CSS */
```

```html
<h1 class="Title">Sign Up</h1>
<div>
 <form method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
  <input type="text" id="Name" name="yourname" placeholder="*Full Name" autocomplete="off" required>
  <input type="email" id="Email" name="youremail" placeholder="*E-Mail"autocomplete="off" required>
  <input type="tel" id="Phone" name="yourphone" placeholder="*Phone" autocomplete="off" required>
  <input type="password" id="Password" name="yourpassword" placeholder="*Password" autocomplete="off" required>
  <p class="signup"> The fields with * are required!<br>
  -If you have an account, <a class="signup" href="reservation.php">log in</a> now-</p>

  <keygen name="security" style="display:none;">
  <input type="submit" value="Register">

    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1: You can use `text-transform: capitalize` CSS property which will automatically do the task of converting a name from `john cena` to `John Cena`.

Check the example below in the CSS

Option 2:
I have added a new input called `Nick name` which uses javascript to do the same task.

I have used `keyup` handler to capture the all key input event so that we can execute a piece of code which will do the job on capitalizing the name.

The result is simple string manipulation which splits the name with `<space-character>` and converts the first character to uppercase and joins the same with rest of the string.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.querySelector("#NickName").addEventListener("keyup", capitalizeName);
});

function capitalizeName() {
  if (!this.value) return;
  var aNewName = this.value.split(" ").map(function(name) {
    return name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1);
  });
  this.value = aNewName.join(" ");
}

function validateForm() {
  for (var i = 0; i < document.forms[0].elements.length; i++) {
    var pedio = document.forms[0].elements[i];
    if (pedio.id.indexOf("Name") != -1) {
      if (pedio.value.length < 5 || pedio.value.length > 35) {
        alert("Full Name must be 5-35 character long");
        pedio.focus();
        pedio.style.backgroundColor = "#997379";
        return false;
      }
    }

    if ((pedio.id.indexOf("Phone") != -1) && (isNaN(pedio.value))) {
      alert("Phone is must contain only numbers");
      pedio.focus();
      pedio.style.backgroundColor = "#997379";
      return false;
    }

    if (pedio.id.indexOf("Phone") != -1) {
      if (pedio.value.length != 10) {
        alert("Phone must be 10 numbers");
        pedio.focus();
        pedio.style.backgroundColor = "#997379";
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
/* No CSS */

#Name {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="Title">Sign Up</h1>
<div>
  <form method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    <input type="text" id="Name" name="yourname" placeholder="*Full Name" autocomplete="off" required>
    <input type="text" id="NickName" name="NickName" placeholder="*Nick name" autocomplete="off" required>
    <input type="email" id="Email" name="youremail" placeholder="*E-Mail" autocomplete="off" required>
    <input type="tel" id="Phone" name="yourphone" placeholder="*Phone" autocomplete="off" required>
    <input type="password" id="Password" name="yourpassword" placeholder="*Password" autocomplete="off" required>
    <p class="signup"> The fields with * are required!<br> -If you have an account, <a class="signup" href="reservation.php">log in</a> now-</p>

    <keygen name="security" style="display:none;">
    <input type="submit" value="Register">

  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I can't understand it.. I don't know much from JQuery yet!

Comment: I have updated it with a much simpler answer. Please check again.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: It's working, but after when I'm importing the data in DB, the name is like the same

Comment: Yes, it doesn't change the actual value. If that is your requirement, you gotta do it via javascript. I will add code snippet for the same

Comment: I have added an example for Javascript. Please check the same

Comment: Thank you so so much!! I understand how you did it.. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

The RegExp object has a method `test` which when given a string argument returns true if there was at least one match in the str or false. [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

Used as `/regexp/.test(str)`. You already have code that tests for length. You want to test for the length AND for this regex.

When you want to capitalize the first letter of each word, that is called `Title Case`. There's an excellent answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196972/convert-string-to-title-case-with-javascript) for that part of your question