# How to make all uppercase in javascript except if string contains '

Tags: javascript

I have the following string:

```
A new way's to get home
```

Output need to be:

```
A New Way's To Get Home
```

I try with this code:

```
var string = "A new way's to get home";

string = string.replace(/\(\d+\)/g, '').trim().replace(': ', ' - ').replace(/\b[a-z]/g,function(f){return f.toUpperCase();});

alert(string);
```

But i get this:

```
A New Way'S To Get Home
```

I need to get all string at begginning to uppercase but here the problem is Way'S because it contains ' and this regex above need to return 's not 'S how i need to rewrite this regex to return correct value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string to title case with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196972/convert-string-to-title-case-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Convert string to title case with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196972/convert-string-to-title-case-with-javascript) is probably what you're looking for. It's called Title Case. Function pasted below for ease of use:

```
function toTitleCase(str)
{
    return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
}
```

credit to Greg Dean