# How do I target specific inputs on a form fields to change output to Title Case?

Tags: javascript, html

On my form I am trying to have specific output fields and their strings output as Title Case. May be worth noting, this form outputs to results on the same page. Here's a [Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6ohs0pc1/) of my form.

As you can see from it I have 3 input categories Name, City and Words, for this example I am trying to implement the Title Case script to just the 'Name" and City" output strings without it effecting the "Words" category. As I don't want to convert an ongoing sentence to Title Case.

I found a lot of discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196972/convert-string-to-title-case-with-javascript) on how to convert to title case. However I am having difficulty implementing this in to my form as I am still new to JavaScript. All the examples show the script, but not how to implement it in a form.

I was playing around with [Greg Dean's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196972/convert-string-to-title-case-with-javascript) top answer to try and target the specific inputs like so...

```
toTitleCase = function(str)
{
var name  = document.getElementById('name');
var city  = document.getElementById('city');

return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return 
txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
}
```

However this does not seem to be working.

Here's the HTMl:

```
<form>
<input type="text" class="text" id="name" placeholder="Name">
<br>
<input type="text" class="text" id="city" placeholder="City">
<br>
<textarea type="textarea" id="words" placeholder="Words" cols="70" rows="6">
</textarea>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Combine" onclick="convert()">
<br>
<div class="wrap"><span id="CharCountLabel1" class="counter"></span>
<textarea type="textarea" name="output" id="output" cols="70" rows="10" 
maxlength='' placeholder="Output"></textarea>
</div>
<br>
<button type="reset" onclick="ResetForm();" value="Reset 
form">Reset form</button>
</form>
```

And the rest of the script:

```
function convert() {
var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
var city = document.getElementById("city").value;
var words = document.getElementById("words").value;
//input = wordwrap(input, 70, true);
var output = "";

if(!document.getElementById("name").disabled){
output += "Name: " + name + "\n";
}

if(!document.getElementById("city").disabled){
output += "City: " + city + "\n";
}    

if(!document.getElementById("words").disabled){
output += "The words are... " + words + "\n";
}

document.getElementById("output").value = output;
}

CharacterCount = function(output,FieldToCount){
var myField = document.getElementById(output);
var myLabel = document.getElementById(FieldToCount);

var Chars =  myField.length;
if(!Chars){Chars =  "" ; };

var remainingChars =   Chars + myField.value.length
myLabel.innerHTML = remainingChars+""+Chars
}

setInterval(function(){CharacterCount('output','CharCountLabel1')},55);
```

How do I target the script to just the specified input fields? Please no jQuery, just JavaScript solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you have a fully-function `toTitleCase()` function, you're never actually **calling** it. All you need to do is run your `name` and `city` variables through your `toTitleCase` function when you go to output them to the page:

```
if (!document.getElementById("name").disabled) {
  output += "Name: " + toTitleCase(name) + "\n";
}
if (!document.getElementById("city").disabled) {
  output += "City: " + toTitleCase(city) + "\n";
}
```

To prevent the `words` from also being transformed, simply don't pass that variable to the function:

```
if (!document.getElementById("words").disabled) {
  output += "The words are... " + words + "\n";
}
```

A working demo of this can be seen **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/o0uuhdcx/)**.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: The defiantly helps, I wondered if there was somewhere I was failing to call it, but didn't realized I could call a function within another function like that. Thank you so much, i really appreciate that :)

Now I might have to try some of those more elaborate examples that also modify names like MacDonald and the like.