# Capitalize first letter of a camelcase string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, camelcasing

I'm trying to obtain a camel case string (but with the first letter capitalized).

I'm using the following regular expression code in JavaScript:

```
String.prototype.toCamelCase = function() {
return this.replace(/^([A-Z])|\s(\w)/g, function(match, p1, p2, offset) {
    if (p2) return p2.toUpperCase();
    return p1.toLowerCase();
});
```

but the first letter is converted to a lower case.

Comment: Please provide us an example input (or a few).

Comment: Have you checked here ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196972/convert-string-to-title-case-with-javascript

Comment: This is exactly what I was searching for!

Answer (score 5):

I would not encourage extending `String` in JavaScript, but anyway to return your string with the first letter in uppercase you can do it like this:

```
String.prototype.toCamelCase = function() {
    return this.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + this.substring(1);
};
```

**Demo:**

```js
    String.prototype.toCamelCase = function() {
        return this.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + this.substring(1);
    };
    
var str = "abcde";
 console.log(str.toCamelCase());
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
String.prototype.toCamelCase = function() {
  return this.replace(/\b(\w)/g, function(match, capture) {
    return capture.toUpperCase();
  }).replace(/\s+/g, '');
}

console.log('camel case this'.toCamelCase());
console.log('another string'.toCamelCase());
console.log('this is actually camel caps'.toCamelCase());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String.prototype.toCamelCase = function() {
   string_to_replace = this.replace(/^([A-Z])|\s(\w)/g, 
      function(match, p1, p2, offset) {
         if (p2) return p2.toUpperCase();
         return p1.toLowerCase();
      });
   return string_to_replace.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string_to_replace.slice(1);
}
```

One simple way would be to manually uppercase the first character!