# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-export-table-to-excel'

Tags: reactjs

I wanted to be exporting the table to excel in react so Installed [react-export-table-to-excel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-export-table-to-excel).
However when I import through `import { DownloadTableExcel } from 'react-export-table-to-excel';` it is giving me the above error I tried installing it globally but it's not working as well/. What can be the problem?
Below is **react-export-table-to-excel** in node modules

[image]

[image]

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "react app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@coreui/coreui": "^4.1.6",
    "@coreui/react": "^4.2.3",
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^2.14.0",
    "@date-io/dayjs": "^2.14.0",
    "@date-io/luxon": "^2.14.0",
    "@date-io/moment": "^2.14.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.9.3",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.9.3",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^5.12.3",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^5.0.0-alpha.7",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers-pro": "^5.0.0-alpha.7",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.5",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.4.0",
    "react-bootstrap-sweetalert": "^5.2.0",
    "react-date-range": "^1.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-export-table-to-excel": "^1.0.3",
    "react-icons": "^4.4.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "rsuite": "^5.15.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: If you have installed ```react-export-table-to-excel``` and getting this error then most likely you haven't restarted your server. Please press ctrl+c on your terminal and do ```npm start``` or ```yarn start```

Comment: I restarted the server but nothing is changing

Comment: Please share your package.json file. Also try deleting node-modules and installing all dependencies

Comment: Done I have shared, let me try deleting all modules.

Comment: Deleting node-modules did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is some issue with the library. Even their GitHub page has an open issue on this here. In this issue people have also suggested one alternative with full tutorial
https://github.com/EdisonJpp/react-export-table-to-excel/issues/3

I would suggest using any other library for this purpose. I tried installing and importing this library but I am having the same issue. I tried all 4 versions of this library but none of them works. Even though these modules are exported from its `index.txs` file but still gives an error.

The sandbox that I used: https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-neumann-t5qyeg?file=/src/App.js

Please check this StackOverflow article to get an alternative to this library
[How to export data to excel using react libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61316889/how-to-export-data-to-excel-using-react-libraries)

Answer (score 0):

Your error says that it was not installed properly. If you can, open command prompt in your react file and run `npm i react-export-table-to-excel` If you still have issues, then we would need to know the code editor that you are using to further assist you.

Many code editors also have a codeless GUI that supports installing dependencies for those who don't want to or can't do it the "old school" way.

Comment: I am using terminal