# A Javascript regular expression for "Title Case" French-names proof

Tags: javascript, regex

I've found a nice RegExp to transform "lower case name" to "Title Case Name" but I've noticed that it doesn't works correctly with French names like "Jean-Marie" that should stay and not transformed into "Jean-marie" and so on.

So, here it is the whole function with the RegExp:

```
function titleCase(source) {
    return source.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt) {
        return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
    });
}
```

So, the question: How can I modify the RegExp to take care also of the French names?

Thanks a lot for the answers!

Comment: It doesn't look like you've made an attempt to solve this yourself. Please show a [mcve] of what you've attempted otherwise this is [off-topic (#1)](/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

This works. For more info [refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196972/convert-string-to-title-case-with-javascript)

The following regex also works for normal cases.
`vignesh raja` = `Vignesh Raja`

```js
var name = "vignesh-raja";
name = name.replace(/\b\w+/g, function(str) {
  return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.substr(1);
});
console.log(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method can take a function as the second parameter with a number of parameters..

From the docs:

`p1, p2, ...`

> The nth parenthesized submatch string, provided the first argument to
>   replace() was a RegExp object. (Corresponds to $1, $2, etc. above.)
>   For example, if /(\a+)(\b+)/, was given, p1 is the match for \a+, and
>   p2 for \b+.

What you could do is use a regex like [`(\w)(\w+(?:-\w+)*)`](https://regex101.com/r/hvY3y5/1) which will match words with a hyphen as 1 word. Then you could capture the first character in the first group, and the rest of the match in the second group.

Then use [toUpperCase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) to convert that character and return the concatenated name.

For example:

```js
function titleCase(source) {
  return source.replace(/(\w)(\w+(?:-\w+)*)/g, function(txt, p1, p2) {
    return p1.toUpperCase() + p2.toLowerCase();
  });
}

var titles = [
  "lower case name",
  "Jean-Marie",
  "JEAN-MARIE",
  "tEST TEST-TEST tesT"
];
for (var i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
  console.log(titles[i] + " ---> " + titleCase(titles[i]));
}
```

**Note**

Using `\w` for names matches `[A-Za-z0-9_]`