# HTML RegEx (First letter to be capitalized)

Tags: html, regex

I have field "first and second name" and I need RegEx for capitalizing first letter in each word in this field.

With this pattern, only first word is capitalized, but second is not

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  First and Second name <input type="text" name="f_and_s_name" pattern="[A-zA-Z]{1,13}" title="">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Your code is not complete. Please post the whole code. The pattern attribute does not modify the value inside input, it only validates it before form submission.

Comment: I added html code to first post.

Comment: Your current regex [also allows `]]]]]]]]]]]]]` input or `^___[]][][`, and lowercase words](https://regex101.com/r/TUbN7k/3). Please explain what you actually are trying to achieve.

Comment: If my first and second name is  "John Doe" I want to validate that input in that field must be with capitalized letter (not to be Johh doe, john Doe or john doe).

Comment: Then the basic regex would be `pattern="[A-Z][a-z]* [A-Z][a-z]*"`.

Comment: That is Wiktor, post it like an answer please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if firstname's and lastname's first characters are uppercase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49239808/how-to-check-if-firstnames-and-lastnames-first-characters-are-uppercase)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pattern="[A-zA-Z]{1,13}"` pattern is parsed by the JS RegExp engine as `^(?:[A-zA-Z]{1,13})$`. It matches a string that consists of 1 to 13 characters that are ASCII letters, and also `[`, `\`, `]`, `^`, `_`, `` ` `` (see [this answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29771926/3832970)).

You plan to only validate strings that start with an uppercase ASCII letter followed with lowercase letters, then have a space, and then again an uppercase ASCII letter followed with lowercase letters.

Then, you may use

```
pattern="[A-Z][a-z]* [A-Z][a-z]*"
```

If you want to make the rule a bit less restricted, you may use `[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*\s+[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*` (this will also allow strings in ALLCAPS, and will allow any 1+ whitespace chars between two letter strings. If you plan to implement Unicode letter support, it will only be easy in latest Chrome versions (it will look like `pattern="\p{Lu}\p{L}*\s+\p{Lu}\p{L}*"`). However, it won't work in all other browsers that still do not support ECMA2018 standard.

Comment: @ Wiktor, this pattern  (pattern="[A-Z][a-z]* [A-Z][a-z]*") is giving me only 3 words in a string.

Comment: @Ovakos What do you mean by "giving" "3 words"? `/^(?:[A-Z][a-z]* [A-Z][a-z]*)$/` only matches a string that consists of exactly 2 ASCII capitalized words.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote fast and I didn't explain well.
This (pattern="\p{Lu}\p{L}*\s+\p{Lu}\p{L}*") works for first and second name, and it is really good pattern. I have field "Adress" witch is in format: String String Number (or numbers) Comma String (My Street 30, NewYork). How can I implement the same thing here mate?

Comment: @Ovakos This is a different question then. I do not understand the requirements, but probably you want `pattern="\p{L}+\s+\p{L}+\s+\p{N}+,.*"`. No idea what you mean by "Number" and "String". When you plan to use regex, you match types of characters, so you must be very specific.

Comment: I will try to implement, and make a new question if it won't work :) Tnx