# How to output title case text into html field using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I am using the following jQuery to allow a user to enter some text into a text field which is then rendered elsewhere on the screen within a div.

I am able to get the text to render in uppercase and lowercase but I'm not too sure how to get it to render in title case, or a mixture of both cases.

This is the code:

```
jQuery('#fhc-sloganText').keyup(function() {

    var plateSlogan = document.getElementById("plateSlogan");

    plateSlogan.innerHTML = this.value.toLowerCase();

});
```

I believe I need to be using RegExp but I'm finding it difficult trying to implement it into this scenario.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string to title case with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196972/convert-string-to-title-case-with-javascript)

Comment: What do you mean by title case ? maybe Title tag ??

Comment: Can you use CSS or do you need the actual value to be title cased? `text-transform: capitalize` would display it properly...

Comment: Actually, @FissureKing, that's by far the best way.

Comment: you can use the capitalize function here : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51346019/4949758)
or simply use `text-transform: capitalize` which i believe is the simplest.

Comment: No, CSS won't work as the field is a product attribute which is passed on to the basket and checkout.  The client then needs to print the exact characters on to the product for the customer. So if they're all uppercase or lowercase, this will be shown in the order. CSS only shows changes on the website front end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this function to capitalize each word in a String.

```
function toTitleCase(str){
  return str.replace(/\b\w/g, l => l.toUpperCase());
}
```

```css
#plateSlogan{
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="fhc-sloganText"/>
<p/>
<div id="plateSlogan"></div>
<script>
jQuery('#fhc-sloganText').keyup(function() {

    var plateSlogan = document.getElementById("plateSlogan");

    plateSlogan.innerHTML = this.value.replace(/\b\w/g, l => l.toUpperCase());

});
</script>
```

You can use this function to capitalize the first word in a String>

```
function capitalizeFirstLetter(str) {
   return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}
```

```css
#plateSlogan{
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="fhc-sloganText"/>
<p/>
<div id="plateSlogan"></div>
<script>
jQuery('#fhc-sloganText').keyup(function() {

    var plateSlogan = document.getElementById("plateSlogan");

    plateSlogan.innerHTML = this.value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.value.slice(1);

});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for that! It's almost perfect. How would I go about amending it so the user can have any case they wish to use. So they could type something like "Hello this is my slogan" instead of how it currently renders it "Hello This Is My Slogan".

Comment: @user2770714 I have edited my answer to suit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this goal much easier. Use CSS:

`plateSlogan.style.textTransform = "capitalize";`

Or, if you are using jQuery, you can use the function [.css](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2)

Comment: No, CSS won't work as the field is a product attribute which is passed on to the basket and checkout. The client then needs to print the exact characters on to the product for the customer. So if they're all uppercase or lowercase, this will be shown in the order. CSS only shows changes on the website front end.

Comment: @user2770714 if that is the case, I recommend you to try hev1's solution. Should work