# regex non converting character after symbol to upper case

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to convert a list of sentences to Title Case. The problem is however that with this regex the character does not get converted if it starts with a symbol. How can I get it to work?

This is a quick example:

```
var ls = ["this is fine" "+this is not"]
var response = ls.map(s => s.toLowerCase().replace(/^(.)|[^\w-'](\w)/gi, match => match.toUpperCase()))
```

I would like response to be `["This Is Fine" "+This Is Not"]` and not `["This Is Fine" "+this Is Not"]` like it is now.

In other words the problem is that `+this` is not capitalized. Same goes if I add `"[this is a string]"` or any other symbol.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string to title case with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196972/convert-string-to-title-case-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`\b` metacharacter](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), which matches at any word boundary.

Then the regular expression becomes:

```
\b\w
```

i.e. "match any word character that follows a word boundary."

See it in action:

```js
var ls = ["this is fine", "+this is not"];
var result = ls.map(s => s.toLowerCase().replace(/\b\w/gi, match => match.toUpperCase()));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hi @aurélien-gasser I thought this worked at the beginning, but then I noticed that it doesn't with non-English characters. Look at this https://jsfiddle.net/oyj63xec/ Do you know how I could catch and capitalize also those? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this**

```
^\W?\w|\W\w
```

> Explanation

- `^` - Anchor to start of string.
- `\W?\w` - Matches any non word character. (? makes it optional). followed by any word character.
- `|` - Alternation works same as logical OR.
- `\W\w` - Matches any non word character followed by a word character.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/E6DbOK/4)

```js
var ls = ["this is fine", "+this is not"]
var response = ls.map(s => 
   s.toLowerCase().replace(/^\W?\w|\W\w/g , 
   match => match.toUpperCase()))
console.log(response);
```

Comment: This captures the `+`, no?

Comment: @Fubert yes but it will not affect answer.as `+`.

Answer (score 0):

You could match either a word character at the start of the string, or not a word character and then a word character:

`^\w|\W(\w)`

```js
var ls = ["this is fine", "+this is not"];
var response = ls.map(s => s.toLowerCase().replace(/^\w|\W(\w)/g, match => match.toUpperCase()))
console.log(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to match the letters at the start of a word that is not preceded with `-` or `'`.

Thus, you may use

```js
var ls = ["this is fine","+this is not", "man-of-war here", "I'm not"]
var response = ls.map(s => s.toLowerCase().replace(/(^|[^-'])\b([a-z])/g, 
    (_, g1, g2) =>  `${g1}${g2.toUpperCase()}`))
console.log(response);
```

The pattern will match

- `(^|[^-'])` - Group 1: start of string or any char other than `-` and `'`
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `([a-z])` - a single ASCII lowercase letter