# Using .toUpperCase and .slice to capitalize first letter isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have JSON data that's rendered via a DataTable and in one of the columns the text shows up as capitalized, and I want it to be like This where only the first letter is uppercase.

As per other posts on SO, it was recommended that `.toUppercase` and `.slice` be used. Based on what I have I feel that my code should be working, but for some reason it isn't. Since I'm working with DataTables I have had to go over a few hurdles to get results, so I'm wondering if DT is at the root of the problem as well.

#### JS snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#matters-table').DataTable({
            columns: [
                { data: "0" },
                { data: "1" },
                { data: "Status" }, // is in all caps when rendered
                { data: "3" }
            ],
            columnDefs: [
                {"targets":2,"render": function(data) {
                    return data[0].toUpperCase() + data.slice(1);
                }}
            ],
            data: mattsText,
            ... // --------------- irrelevant info.
```

Any thoughts on this one?

Comment: what do you mean by "it isn't (working)"? Please share your input data, the expected output, and the actual output.

Comment: Expected output: Lookslikethis --- Actual output: LOOKSLIKETHIS . The text looks like the actual output by default.

Comment: and what's the input? (I ask because it's possible it's already all capitalised, even if you don't think it is.)

Comment: Please [edit] your question, preferably reducing the code to a [mcve]. Note that you can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to do so.

Comment: The input is in all caps by default. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: What do you get when you do do console.log(data); ?

Comment: Please also link to the posts that suggest using `toUpperCase` and `slice`. It looks like you're implementing it differently, since those functions should be run on the same string, and you're applying the first to `data[0]` and the second to `data` (no `[0]`)...

Comment: well if the input is all in caps, you want to convert all but the first letter to lowercase. If you do `return data[0].toUpperCase() + data.slice(1).toLowerCase();` then you'll get the casing you want no matter what mixture of cases the input is in

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string to title case with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196972/convert-string-to-title-case-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Use the following `capitalize` function as your render function (note the added `split`):

```js
capitalize = str => str.split('')[0].toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);

console.log(capitalize('hello world'));
```