# How can I uppercase the first letter of every word in a string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

The following function should uppercase the first letter of every word in a sentence (str)! Unfortunately it doesn't work and I cant find the solution!

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  let arr = str.toLowerCase().split(" ");
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase();
  }
  return arr.join(" ");
}

console.log(titleCase("I'm a little tea pot"));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string to title case with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196972/convert-string-to-title-case-with-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign the result of uppercasing the letter, and concatenate it to the rest of the word:

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  let arr = str.toLowerCase().split(" ");
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = arr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + arr[i].substring(1);
  }
  return arr.join(" ");
}

console.log(titleCase("I'm a little tea pot"));
```

It's also easier to use `map`:

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  return str.split(" ").map(s => s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1)).join(" ");
}

console.log(titleCase("I'm a little tea pot"));
```

Answer (score 1):

`arr` is an array of strings, but strings are immutable - simply calling `toUpperCase()` on a character will just give you a reference to a *new, uppercase* character, without changing the original string. You need to explicitly reassign the array item:

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  let arr = str.toLowerCase().split(" ");
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = arr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + arr[i].slice(1);
  }
  return arr.join(" ");
}

console.log(titleCase("I'm a little tea pot"));
```

Or, perhaps more elegantly, you could use a regular expression. The following uses lookbehind, which works in recent versions of Chrome, Opera, and Node; lookbehind makes for cleaner-looking code, but it's not supported everywhere:

```js
const titleCase = str => str.replace(
  /(?<=^|\s)\S/g,
  firstChar => firstChar.toUpperCase()
);

console.log(titleCase("I'm a little tea pot"));
```

Or, without lookbehind:

```js
const titleCase = str => str.replace(
  /(\S)(\S*)/g,
  (_, firstChar, rest) => firstChar.toUpperCase() + rest
);

console.log(titleCase("I'm a little tea pot"));
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I am just a beginner! You helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can update your code this way

- First lowercase all the characters
- Loop through string indexes
- If index is `0` or `index - 1` is a space character make the `str[index]` to uppercase
- Keep appending it a string and return at end

```js
function titleCase(str) {
 let LowerCaseStr = str.toLowerCase()
 let final =''
 for (let i = 0; i < LowerCaseStr.length; i++) {
   if(i === 0 || LowerCaseStr[i-1] === ' '){
     final += LowerCaseStr[i].toUpperCase()
   } else{
     final += LowerCaseStr[i]
   }
 }
return final
}

console.log(titleCase("I'm a little tea pot"));
```