# CSS title casing with proper adherence to lowercase short prepositions ("and", "of", "in", etc.)

Tags: css, text, title

eg.: if the source text is mixed or improper:

`here is a string of text for a title`

The linguisitcally correct capitalizing is:

**Here is a String of Text for a Title**

Using `text-transform: capitalize` will result in:

**Here Is A String Of Text For A Title**

Is there any CSS property and/or value that can be applied to transform text into the proper English title case?

Comment: I think there is no such thing in css, there are solutions in javascript or ruby. The code isnt long. Ruby version: https://github.com/samaaron/titlecase-rb/blob/master/title_case.rb

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is presently no way to title case text with CSS. However there are lots of options for doing so via JavaScript: [Convert string to title case with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196972/convert-string-to-title-case-with-javascript)

Comment: Thanks, that's what I figured.  I'll just use javascript to accomplish this, then.