# How can I make this javascript to capitilize all first letter of a field?

Tags: javascript

How can I edit this code to make "This name input field" to be "This Name Input Field"?
Can anyone give me a light? :)

EDIT: I'm really noob, I don't know nothing about javascript, just trying to edit this code to get first letters capitilized.

```
function wpf_dev_capitalize() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery( '.wpforms-field.capitalize input' ).keyup(function() {
                jQuery(this).val(jQuery(this).val().substr(0,1).toUpperCase() +    jQuery(this).val().substr(1).toLowerCase());
                });
        jQuery( '.wpforms-field.capitalize textarea' ).keyup(function() {
                jQuery(this).val(jQuery(this).val().substr(0,1).toUpperCase() +    jQuery(this).val().substr(1).toLowerCase());
            });
    });
    </script>
<?php
}
add_action( 'wpforms_wp_footer_end', 'wpf_dev_capitalize', 30 );
```

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/three-ways-to-title-case-a-sentence-in-javascript-676a9175eb27/

Comment: `text-transform: capitalize;` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string to Title Case with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196972/convert-string-to-title-case-with-javascript)

Comment: @zhibirc where do I put it? If it's CSS I already inserted it in the page

Answer (score -1):

```
        const capitalize_first_letter = string =>{
           let stringArr = string.split(' ');
           return stringArr.map(word=>{
              let splitWord = word.split('')
              let capitalized = splitWord[0].toUpperCase();
              splitWord.shift();
             
         
  splitWord.unshift(capitalized)
              return splitWord.join('')
           }).join(' ');
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try. I add this to my code without editing anything?

Comment: I'm too noob, I can't add it without messing the code LOL :(

Answer (score -1):

To avoid reinventing the wheel, one possible solution is just use something like **lodash** (as a "standard library") in the project for every trivial cases in your project like this:

```js
import { startCase } from "lodash";

console.log(startCase("This name input field")); // This Name Input Field
```

Comment: I dont know how to do it, thanks anyway :)