# Javascript: title Case with replace method

Tags: javascript, replace

I want to convert the given string to a title case:

```js
const titleCase = function (text) {
  if (text === "") return "";
  let textArr = text.split(" ");
  const outputArr = textArr.map(
    ele => ele.toLowerCase().replace(ele[0], ele[0].toUpperCase())
  );
  const output = outputArr.join(" ");
  return output;
};

const test1 = titleCase("this is an example"); 
const test2 = titleCase("WHAT HAPPENS HERE");
console.log(test1);
console.log(test2);
```

`test1` gives me the right result `This Is An Example` but test2 returns `what happens here` which is not the result that I want.

I am confused... where did it go wrong?

Comment: "which is not the result that I want" --- you have not explained what you want.

Comment: @zerkms OP says _"title case"_ so I imagine _"What Happens Here"_

Comment: @Phil it says `title Case` not cased properly though :-D

Comment: Fair . @Ben could you please [edit] your question to explain the result you want, just for clarity

Comment: @Ben in your code you `ele.toLowerCase()` but then you refer to the _original_ character in the `ele[0]` (twice). If you want to implement it that way - you should `ele[0].toLowerCase()`

Comment: Your issue is that `ele[0]` is no longer in the lowercased string

Comment: FYI converting strings to title case has [many existing solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/196972/283366)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string to Title Case with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196972/convert-string-to-title-case-with-javascript)

Comment: _"Where did it go wrong?"_ is _exactly_ the kind of question that a debugger is good at helping you answer.  You should learn how to use your debugger to inspect the pieces of a large expression like `ele.toLowerCase().replace(ele[0], ele[0].toUpperCase())`. In the case where an expression isn't working as you expected, you can break it into smaller pieces and assign sub-expressions to variables with meaningful names so that you can inspect them or log them.  I think you would have figured this out yourself if you had done some debugging.  It takes effort, but as devs, we should all learn how.

Comment: @Wyck Totally agreed! "Breaking into smaller pieces."  This enlightened me. Thank you, Wyck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run it on the `test2` string, each `ele` in your map function is the upper case word. When you attempt to replace `ele[0]` in your function, it is looking for the upper case character in a string that has no upper case letters. ie with 'WHAT' you're looking to replace `ele[0]` which is `W` in the string `what`.
Try:

```
ele => ele.toLowerCase().replace(ele[0].toLowerCase(), ele[0].toUpperCase())
```

Comment: I would have tackled the problem earlier on in the process, by doing `let textArr = text.toLowerCase().split(" ");`

Comment: That answered my question! I finally understand how replace works in JS, thank you so much Richard :)

Comment: @Ben, please try to use simple solution using chatAt and slice.

Comment: @Wyck I should've done this way :(  Your approach is better, Wyck. Thank you!

Comment: @Topdev I tried and it worked! Will use that, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can turn a string to lowerCase before, and then make the code more  readable:

```
const titleCase = string => string
  .toLowerCase()
  .split(' ')
  .map(i => i.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + i.slice(1))
  .join(' ')
```

or es5:

```
function titleCase(string) {
  return string
    .toLowerCase()
    .split(" ")
    .map(function (i) {
      return i.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + i.slice(1);
    })
    .join(" ");
}
```